# How to reinstall wifi card driver?

Tags: drivers

I would like to reinstall the driver of my wifi card. In order to find out the name of my driver, I have used:

`sudo lshw -C network`

and the output for the wifi card is

```
*-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 4c:bb:58:dc:ad:10
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.2.0-30-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:19 ioport:1000(size=256) memory:90400000-90403fff
```

Therefore, I think the device name is `RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter`.

Can anybody guide me how to reinstall its driver again?

Comment: How did you install that driver the first time? And why do you want to re-install it?

Comment: It has been installed automatically when I installed Ubuntu. It works very well after turning on the computer. However, after sometime, 10 to 15 minutes, the internet disconnects. It is still connected to the router, but I cannot access internet. Other devices that are connected to the router still work very well. Therefore, the problem is not from router. I have also checked the **power saving** settings of the wireless card and it is off (as I think it should be off).

Comment: When I restart my comupter, I have access to the internet, but again, after a few minutes, the internet disconnects. It may be a problem in the driver and I want to reinstall or possibly find another driver.

Answer (score -2):

Search for "Software Sources" on the dash. On the "Additional drivers" tab, you should find your wifi card's driver, most likely disabled. Enable it and apply changes.[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDyRG.jpg)

Comment: Additional drivers is applicable only to Broadcom adapters.