# Cannot see my wifi [10ec:d723] when trying Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, system-installation, realtek-wireless

I am having an issue with wifi; it seems when I'm trying Ubuntu without installing, it only detects connection via the ethernet cable.

I can't connect and none of the available wifi networks are detected.

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 5904 (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5916 (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d10 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d4e (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d71 (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330] (rev 83)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d723
```

---

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
    DeviceName: Hanksville Gbe Lan Connection
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
```

Comment: I had also a Realtek wifi card and I remember I needed to install another driver for that. Check this question; it might help you:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/747896/how-to-reinstall-wifi-card-driver

Comment: Please see this newer answer - a driver has become available [https://askubuntu.com/questions/983251/wi-fi-problem-no-icon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983251/wi-fi-problem-no-icon)

Comment: Why not the other question is a duplicate of this? `jeremyb31/rtl8723de` is a forked from `smlinux/rtl8723de` and this Question is more old than the "duplicated" question. Can someone explain , please?

Answer (score 11):

A linux driver is available on [smlinux/rtl8723de](https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de)

Requirements :

A linux kernel >= 4.11

The appropriate `linux-headers` to your kernel version should be installed.

```
git clone https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de
cd rtl8723de
make 
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -v 8723de
```

The `dkms` way (the instructions from the developer's driver):

```
git clone https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723.git -b 4.11-up
sudo dkms add ./rtl8723de
sudo dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
sudo depmod -a
sudo reboot
```

**Update:**

To install a kernel version greater than `4.11` you can use the [`ukuu`](https://github.com/teejee2008/ukuu) tool.

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ukuu
```

To list the available kernel version:

```
sudo ukuu --list
```

To install a specific kernel version (e.g: `4.11.12`):

```
sudo ukuu --install v4.11.12
```

See `ukuu --help`.

[Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds) : To install a [mailine kernel](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) with the appropriate `linux-headers` package.

Comment: Great man!!! You saved my life... I've just bought a new laptop and my wifi not working. I'm trying to make it work from 2 days and now you made it... Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @GAD3R can you elaborate this process for me please actually I'm new to this community and don't know how to properly use the command line.
And are you sure that this will definitely work??

Comment: @KennethToppo Install `git` and the `linux-heasers` package then copy and past the 5 first lines of code to your terminal .

Comment: @GAD3R how do i upgrade to kernel 4.11

Comment: @KennethToppo See the update

Comment: Working perfectly but getting uninstalled whenever i got ubuntu update.

Comment: Simply Great !!

Comment: @GAD3R thanks a lot! The first set of instructions worked for me

Comment: Do i need to install make on my ubuntu??

Answer (score 6):

This device `Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d723` is not supported by Linux yet.

It is `rtl8723de`. There are no vendor drivers either.

**Update:** The device is supported by Linux 5.3+ now.

Comment: iwfiger say it will be available in 3 month : [The driver for RTL8723DE will be ready on 2017 Q4](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/270)

Comment: Arent we in 2017??
@GAD3R

Comment: We are in 2017, but Q4 just started 2 days ago.

Comment: @KennethToppo it will be available in 3 month from now (see the comment of iwfinger)

Comment: Why do you cal him `iwfinger`? He is `lwfinger`. Larry W. Finger.

Comment: @Pilot6 The driver is ready here https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de , a kernel version >= 4.11 is required .

Comment: @GAD3R So why not write a good answer with installation directions?

Answer (score 1):

An unofficial Linux driver is available https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de. You have to compile module using make. Then, install, 8723de module.