# Realtek Network/Wireless Driver not detected

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, hp, realtek

I recently got a new laptop and I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. It is unable to detect the wireless drivers.

Tried: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new - No Detection.

Tried: installing `sudo apt install rtlwifi_new-dkms` - No go.

**System Information:**

```
Manufacturer: HP
Product Name: HP Laptop 15q-bu0xx
Version: Type1ProductConfigId
Serial Number: CND7320DQD
UUID: 805531E3-F277-E711-B753-186024BEECB0
Wake-up Type: Power Switch
SKU Number: 2LS59PA#ACJ
Family: 103C_5335KV HP Notebook
```

**Network Hardware:**

```
- 01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
    RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)

 - 02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d723
```

**ifconfig output:**

```
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 18:60:24:be:ec:b0  
      inet addr:192.168.0.100  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::80b3:39a0:695a:e93c/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:18904 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:13915 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:19799702 (19.7 MB)  TX bytes:1643667 (1.6 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5095 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5095 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:404876 (404.8 KB)  TX bytes:404876 (404.8 KB)
```

also tried,

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be - no output, doesn't throw any errors.
sudo modprobe rtl8723be - no change.
restarted network-manager - no change.
```

I Read all the related posts and still the problem exist.
I am not sure, if the drivers i am installing are correct?

Edit:

Command:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
```

Output:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
DeviceName: WLAN
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
```

Comment: Is there any solution? i followed your repo for any clues.

Comment: There is no solution.

Comment: Please see this newer answer - a driver has become available.  [https://askubuntu.com/a/989152/283721](https://askubuntu.com/a/989152/283721)