# WiFi is not working in Ubuntu 17.04 with rtl8723de

Tags: drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless

My WiFi is not working in Ubuntu 17.04. it is working fine in Windows 10 . I tried to download additional driver but there is no additional driver except one which I unchangeable. It is also showing developer option tab in system setting. I have i5 7th gen processor with 8 GB RAM and AMD 64. I also did update and upgrade to but WiFi remains same there is no options for WiFi in Ubuntu 17.04.

My WiFi card is Realtek rtl8723de 802.11 b/g/n pcle adapter

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: realtek semiconductor Co. Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
DeviceName : hanksville Gbe lan connection
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard company Device [103c:8319]

$ sudo lshw -class network
*-network
  description: Ethernet interface
 Product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI EXPRESS gigabit Ethernet controller
Vendor: realtek semiconductor co..,Ltd
Physical id: 0
Bus info pci@000:02:00.0
Logical name eno1
Version :15
Serial : 18:60:24:14:60:b6
Size:10 Mbit/s
Width: 64bits
Clock : 33MHz
Capabilities: pm Mai pciexpress msix bus_ master cap_ list Ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt- fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
Configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast =yeah driver= r8169 driver version = 2.3LK-NAPI duplex= half firmware= rtl8168h-2_0.0:02/26/15 latency=0

*-network UNCLAMED
 Description: network controller
Product: realtek semiconductor co.ltd
Vendor: realtek semiconductor co.ltd
Physical id = 0
Bus info pci@0000:03:00.0
Version :00
Width: 64 bits
Clock 33MHZ
Capabilities: pm Mai pciexpress bus_master cap_list
Configuration latency =0
Resources: ioport:3000( size= 256 memory:b1000000-b100ffff
*-network
Description: Ethernet interface
Physical id :3
Logical name enp0s20f0u2
Serial: 1a:88 :2e:a7:12:64
Capabilities: Ethernet physical
Configuration: broadcast=yes driver= rndis_host driverversion = 22-aug-2005 firmware= RNDIS
```

Comment: There is a bug in network-manager in Ubuntu 17.04: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1681513     It might be causing trouble in your case.

Comment: How can I fix them

Comment: Did you check the link given in second comment. If the problem you are facing is indeed caused by the mentioned bug, you will be able to get an answer in that link.

Comment: Yes i did that but result is same

Comment: It doesn't even showing any WiFi options

Comment: Would you please edit your question and add the output of 'sudo lshw -class network'

Comment: While giving this command 'sudo lshw -class network it is showing bunch of results

Comment: Yes. Please copy the whole part mentioning Wireless Interface and paste it in your question.

Comment: I put that all in my question

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how to do that I m new to Linux.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command. Most likely it is a `rtl8723de` device, that is not supported.

Comment: I added everything u asked for

Comment: The device is not supported https://askubuntu.com/questions/961299/cannot-see-my-wifi-10ecd723-when-trying-ubuntu/961311?s=1|23.0444#961311

Comment: So u r saying there is no way to fix this @pilot6

Comment: Yeah both seems same problem