# Does my wifi card Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d723 support Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, compatibility

I'm having a hard time getting Ubuntu MATE to connect to wifi. I'm starting to wonder if maybe my wifi card doesn't support Linux. when I type `lspci` into the command line i can see my Network controller is:

```
Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d723
```

I don't know how to tell if it supports Ubuntu so if anybody could let me know I would very much appreciate it :-)

Comment: If you do a Google search on the string "Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d723", you will find a lot of similar complaints. However, in post "https://askubuntu.com/questions/961299/cannot-see-my-wifi-10ecd723-when-trying-ubuntu" it is stated that a driver will become available in Q4 2017. Whether that will come true remains to be seen. In the meantime you might be better of buying a cheap USB dongle... just a thought.

Comment: Thank you, hopefully they become available soon. iv been looking at this usb  Wireless adapter https://www.amazon.com/Panda-300Mbps-Wireless-USB-Adapter/dp/B00EQT0YK2/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1510958529&sr=1-1&keywords=linux+wireless+adapter any advice on buying these?

Comment: Before you buy any device, even a cheap one, read the reviews. Both on its website. Obviously you check the reviews from Ubuntu users and whether they had install problems and if they fixed it.  Preferably you want a device that is recognized by one of many drivers already embedded in Ubuntu. For any device you purchase,  verify you can return it if it doesn't work. I had good experience with TP-Link 723N and Sitecom (forgot the type number, sold it along with a old laptop).

Comment: Please see this newer answer - a driver has become available [https://askubuntu.com/questions/983251/wi-fi-problem-no-icon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983251/wi-fi-problem-no-icon)