# Installing Wi-Fi driver for Realtek Semiconductor RTL8723DE Device [10ec:d723]

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless

How do I install Wi-Fi drivers for Realtek RTL8723DE device in Ubuntu 16.04?

```
lspci -v | grep -i network
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d723
```

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: Wi-Fi is usually automatically installed. Open your terminal with <Ctrl>+<Alt>+T and type `lspci -v | grep -i network` copy the screen output and add it to your question.

Comment: heidy@heidy-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx:~$ lspci -v | grep -i network
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d723
heidy@heidy-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx:~$

Comment: The requested command does not identify the WiFi device correctly. Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command instead.

Comment: These are the information that come, but I still can not access the wireless network                                                                                                                                                                         heidy@heidy-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx:~$ sudo lsmod | grep r81
[sudo] senha para heidy: 
r8169                  81920  0
mii                    16384  1 r8169
heidy@heidy-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx:~$ lspci -v | grep -i network
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d723
heidy@heidy-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx:~$

Comment: What do you mean by _no icon_ here exactly? Please [edit] your question and include the output of `nmcli d status` as well.

Comment: The bluetooth device can also be activated. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033968/how-to-activate-bluetooth-device-for-rtl8723de

Answer (score 26):

You may use the driver hosted at Larry Finger's `rtlwifi_new` [git repository](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new). You would have to disable secure boot from the the BIOS/EFI first. Also make sure you have `linux-headers` for the respective kernel(s) and `build-essential` package installed. Then follow the steps below (you need to be connected to the internet by some other mean).

1. Install `git` and `dkms` if they're not installed by running

   ```
   sudo apt install git dkms
   ```
2. Clone the repository

   ```
   git clone -b extended --single-branch https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
   ```
3. Run the following commands to install

   ```
   sudo dkms add rtlwifi_new
   sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
   ```
4. Reboot.

This should also work with newer kernels (and hence on Ubuntu 18.04 too).

**Note:** If you get very weak signal try changing your antenna selection

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf <<< "options rtl8723de ant_sel=2"
```

(or `ant_sel=1` if 2 doesn't help).

([Source](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Wireless-and-Networking/Realtek-8723DE-wifi-module-Linux-driver-available-now-Ubuntu/td-p/6477307))

---

See this for Bluetooth: [How to activate bluetooth device for RTL8723DE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033968/how-to-activate-bluetooth-device-for-rtl8723de)

Comment: This worked for me. The laptop I use is HP BS180TX. Ubuntu version 18.04 LTS. Kernel 4.15.0-20-generic.

Comment: The DKMS install is preferable. I suggest leaving only the DKMS way or explaining that. Newbies run all the commands and have trouble.

Comment: it mount the interface under /sys/class/net and ip link show the wireless listed, but i can't ip link set interface up, itsn't not effective, any idea why?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/469809/wireless-module-state-cant-be-rendered-up can you help?

Comment: This worked for me. My laptop model is `15q-ds0009TU`

Comment: This didn't work for me, but [THIS](https://askubuntu.com/a/988933/375529) did.

Comment: @pomsky Will these commands work for me as well ? This is my ethernet  - product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller and I have a Dell vostro 3800

Comment: Working on 19.10, kernel 5-3-0*, HP 14q-cs0025TU.

Comment: Not working 18.04.3 fresh install Kernel 5.0.0-23-generic HP 15 db0xxx, Device [10ec:d723] secure boot off, can't `make` Fails no gcc, can't install gcc, Can't invoke DKMS can't install dkms using working lan. Opening a new question doesn't make sense to me but I will if asked to or if no comment finds me I am truly perplexed. dkms depends dpkg-dev - will not be installed

Comment: NOW working HP Notebook - 15-db0015dx same as above comment.  Re-installed 18.04.3 with wired lan connection updated during install and directly after, then followed steps above. However I was careful to install dkms first, then git, just to be sure I did not get the broken packages as before.  It may be important to have a wired Lan connected to avoid issues such as I had. Its nice to have this behind me - Thanks for all the great information.

Comment: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git gives me a http 404: not found error page

Answer (score 11):

There is new information on this device! With a temporary working internet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential dkms git
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8723de.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8723de
sudo dkms build rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
sudo dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
```

Reboot and let us hear your report.

This won't work for Ubuntu 18.04 because of the new kernel incompatibility.

Comment: I think `dkms install` is necessary too (which invokes `build` if necessary).

Comment: when I'm trying to execute last command it shows this: `Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area....
'make' all KVER=4.15.3-041503-generic....(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8723de: 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.3-041503-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/make.log for more information.`

Comment: @JayPatel I suggest that you start your own new question and include the result of: dkms status.

Comment: When I tried this got an error when executing the 5th command. 
`ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8723de: 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-20-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/make.log for more information.`

Comment: @arshad  suggest that you start your own new question and include the result of: `cat /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/make.log `

Comment: @chili555 This is my network card - product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller. Will the same commands work for me as well ?

Comment: @gansub That is ethernet, not wireless.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep secure boot enabled, then the previously posted solutions probably will not work for you. Instead I kept secure boot enabled and did the following:

Create a set of keys for signing:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout MOK.priv -outform DER -out MOK.der -nodes -days 36500 -subj "/CN=Descriptive common name/"
```

Import the key. You'll be prompted for a password here, which you'll need to remember. Your BIOS should prompt you for the password after the reboot.

```
sudo mokutil --import MOK.der
```

Restart:

```
reboot
```

You should have been prompted by your BIOS for the password. Assuming that worked, then you'll want to test that your MOK was successfully enrolled.

```
mokutil --test-key MOK.der
```

Now that your MOK has been enrolled. You'll need to install the drivers for you wifi.

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
git checkout extended
sudo make install
```

You're drivers are available for adding to your kernel, but you need to sign them first before adding them because you have secure boot enabled. So use the keys you generated earlier to sign your drivers.

```
sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der $(modinfo -n rtlwifi)
sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der $(modinfo -n rtl_pci)
sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der $(modinfo -n btcoexist)
sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der $(modinfo -n rtl8723-common)
sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der $(modinfo -n phydm_mod)
sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der $(modinfo -n rtl8723de)
```

Finally, add the `rtl8723de` drivers to the kernel in this order

```
sudo modprobe -r rtlwifi
sudo modprobe rtlwifi
sudo modprobe -r rtl_pci
sudo modprobe rtl_pci
sudo modprobe -r btcoexist
sudo modprobe btcoexist
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723-common
sudo modprobe rtl8723-common
sudo modprobe -r phydm_mod
sudo modprobe phydm_mod
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de
sudo modprobe rtl8723de
```

---

On a side note: for the final step you might be able to get away with just writing:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de
sudo modprobe rtl8723de
```

`modprobe` knows which drivers `rtl8723de` depends on and should therefore be able to add everything that `rtl8723de` depends on along with `rtl8723de`. However, I didn't add my drivers this way and thus, can't guarantee this option will work.

---

Sources: [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047245/wifi-adapter-not-found-in-ubuntu-18-04), [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760671/could-not-load-vboxdrv-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-and-i-want-to-keep-secur), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073152/how-to-get-complete-dependency-list-of-kernel-modules-at-runtime)

Comment: Hi @johnnyodonnell, so I was helping a student with this specific card and I have to say thank you. From a couple of days of researching the ONLY one that helped in the case of using Secure Boot was your answer. +1 to you and the amount of time and dedication you put into this because, going through it, step by step, we had no issues at all and it solved the whole wifi problem. Thank you friend.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado Wow - that's awesome! Glad to hear it worked for you!

Answer (score 2):

#### Realtek RTL8723DE module for Linux kernel 5 and later

Install:

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install build-essential dkms git
git clone https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de.git -b current
sudo dkms add ./rtl8723de
sudo dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
sudo depmod -a
sudo reboot
```

Uninstall:

```
sudo rmmod -f 8723de
sudo dkms uninstall rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
sudo dkms remove rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414 --all
sudo depmod -a
sudo reboot
```

Comment: I have kernel 5.10.0 on debian 10.9; and i couldn't do `dkms install`. complete log: https://pastebin.com/bbhtmw2d. how do i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

For kernels 4.19+ drivers for RTL8822BE, RTL8822CE, RTL8821CE, and RTL8723DE are located in `rtw88` branch of Larry Finger's git repo.

Install them by running

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git
sudo dkms add ./rtw88
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```