# Cannot connect to WiFi on Ubuntu 14.04.5

Tags: 14.04, wireless, hp, realtek, realtek-wireless

Wifi driver not being detected on Ubuntu 14.04.5.
device: hp 15 bw096au powered by AMD a6-9220.

`sudo dkms status`

Output:

```
bcmwl, 6.30.223.248+bdcom, 4.4.0-112-generic, x86_64: installed
r8168, 8.037.00: added
rtl8723de, 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414: added
rtlwifi-new, 0.10~trusty, 4.4.0-112-generic, x86_64: installed
```

---

`sudo dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414`

Output:

```
Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area....
'make' all KVER=4.4.0-112-generic.....(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8723de: 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.4.0-112-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/make.log for more information.
```

`modinfo rtl8723de | grep file`

Output:

```
modinfo: ERROR: Module rtl8723de not found.
```

`rfkill list all`

Output:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`sudo modprobe rtl8723de`

Output:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8723de not found.
```

---

`sudo dkms remove rtlwifi-new/0.10~trusty`

> Output:

```
Error! Invalid number of parameters passed.
Usage: `remove <module>/<module-version> --all`
   or: `remove <module>/<module-version> -k <kernel-version>`
```

---

`sudo dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414`

Output:

```
Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area....
'make' all KVER=4.4.0-112-generic.....(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8723de: 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.4.0-112-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/make.log for more information.
```

`make`
Output:
`make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-112-generic/build M=/home/kazi/rtl8723de  modules make[1]: Entering directory` /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-112-generic'
CC [M]  /home/kazi/rtl8723de/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /home/kazi/rtl8723de/include/drv_types.h:32:0,
from /home/kazi/rtl8723de/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/home/kazi/rtl8723de/include/osdep_service.h:41:33: fatal error: linux/sched/signal.h: No such file or directory
#include <linux/sched/signal.h>
^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [/home/kazi/rtl8723de/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [*module*/home/kazi/rtl8723de] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-112-generic' make: *** [modules] Error 2` 
output for `cat /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de

```
5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/make.log`                   DKMS make.log for rtl8723de-5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414 for kernel 4.15.0-20-generic (x86_64)
Sat May 12 02:13:04 IST 2018
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic'
Makefile:976: "Cannot use CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel"
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/osdep_service.h:41:0,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/drv_types.h:32,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/osdep_service_linux.h: In function ‘_init_timer’:
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/osdep_service_linux.h:287:8: error: ‘_timer {aka struct timer_list}’ has no member named ‘data’
  ptimer->data = (unsigned long)cntx;
        ^~
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/osdep_service_linux.h:288:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_timer’; did you mean ‘_init_timer’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  init_timer(ptimer);
  ^~~~~~~~~~
  _init_timer
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/drv_types.h:32:0,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/osdep_service.h: In function ‘thread_enter’:
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/osdep_service.h:369:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘allow_signal’; did you mean ‘do_signal’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  allow_signal(SIGTERM);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
  do_signal
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/osdep_service.h: In function ‘flush_signals_thread’:
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/osdep_service.h:391:6: error: implicit declaration of function ‘signal_pending’; did you mean ‘timer_pending’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  if (signal_pending(current))
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      timer_pending
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/osdep_service.h:392:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘flush_signals’; did you mean ‘do_signal’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   flush_signals(current);
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
   do_signal
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_cmd.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
Makefile:1552: recipe for target '_module_/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic'
Makefile:1884: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Comment: You asked the question previously, we showed you that the exact same wireless device was asked about and answered previously. Did you try the steps in the link? What went wrong when you did? The answer is still exactly the same.

Comment: "Still doesn't help" doesn't really tell us anything useful. Were there errors or warnings after any of the commands? Did you try a reboot? Are there any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep rtl`

Comment: dmesg | grep rtl
[   11.878650] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=000d lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=8723
[   11.878658] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin

Comment: Again, were there errors or warnings after any of the commands? Did you try a reboot?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: `sudo dkms status` and also: `modinfo rtl8723de | grep file` and also: `rfkill list all` and also: `sudo modprobe rtl8723de`

Comment: can you edit to add results from terminal for `history | grep rtl8723de; cat ~/rtl8723de/.git/HEAD`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Realtek Semiconductor RTL8723DE Device d723 issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983251/realtek-semiconductor-rtl8723de-device-d723-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few instances where a *dkms* module was added, but not fully installed.

```
sudo dkms remove rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414 --all
```

If there are any errors after any of these commands, *STOP* and post them here. Do not proceed until these errors are fixed.

If there are no errors, then do:

```
sudo rm -rf rtl8723de
git clone -b 4.10-down https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8723de.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8723de
sudo dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
```

Then reboot.

Again, if there is any error, stop and tell us so we can fix it first.

Comment: Please see my edit above. I have amended the commands. Try again and stop if there are any errors.

Comment: I'm working on it. I have called upon Jeremy, the github contributor to ask for help but I've not heard back yet. I think many timezones separate you, me and Jeremy.

Comment: While we wait for Jeremy, please try an experiment. From the terminal: `cd rtl8723de` and then: `make clean` and next: `git pull` and finally: `make` Does it end without any errors? Warnings are probably OK.

Comment: Jeremy and I have a theory as to what went wrong. I will edit my answer to propose a slightly improved procedure. Please start at the beginning and follow each step carefully. Stop and post if there are errors.

Comment: Only the "make" command gave an error.

Comment: Same Wifi problem again after upgrading to ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: `sudo dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414`

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' all KVER=4.15.0-20-generic....(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8723de: 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-20-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/make.log for more information.

Comment: What does the log report? `cat /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/make.log` How about: `sudo dkms status`

Comment: This is a complicated issue and since you have now changed to 18.04, I think you need a new question. In short, we'll dkms remove, remove the downloaded file and then git clone the 4.11-up branch. You can certainly try all that yourself but if you need specific guidance, please start a new question.