# Install RealtekRTL8723DE On Ubuntu 16.04LTSon an HP 15-BW005LA

Tags: 14.04, drivers, realtek-wireless

The output to `uname -rs` is:

```
Linux 4.16.0-999-lowlatency
```

The output to `iwconfig` is:

```
enp2s0    no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

The output to `sudo modprobe 8723de` is:

```
[sudo] password for chinodroid: 
modprobe: FATAL: Module 8723de not found in directory /lib/modules/4.16.0-999-lowlatency
```

Answer (score 0):

The rtl8723de driver is in the extended branch of lwfinger's GitHub repo. The driver will make its way into the Linux kernel supplied with Ubuntu eventually, but if you need the driver now, you can build and install it yourself.

Step 1 is to compile the WiFi drivers in lwfinger's repo. Feel free to modify the number appended to the `-j` flag on `make` to change the number of parallel build jobs to suit the system, for instance, if memory is low.

```
$ git clone --branch extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git >/dev/null 2>&1
$ cd rtlwifi_new && make -j8
```

Step 2 is to install the driver and reboot. After the restart, the driver should load automatically, but if it doesn't, it can be manually loaded with `modprobe`.

```
$ sudo make install
$ sudo reboot
[ system reboots ]
$ lsmod |grep --quiet rtl8723de || sudo modprobe rtl8723de
```

Comment: And how does this help the OP install the above?  (we have a duplicate already [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983251/realtek-semiconductor-rtl8723de-device-d723-issue) )  Please note that if you want to get rid of the negative reputation points accrued by an answer, you can always delete that answer and the negative points will be reversed by the system...

Comment: Understood. That's why I mentioned it.  Next time when you google, google with `site:askubuntu.com` first and flag / close as duplicate first.  **:-)**

Comment: Hey, please don't let the fear that there might possibly be a reasonable dupe target out there *somewhere* deter you from answering questions :) Aside from that, I don't think my toaster can cope with more than 6 threads, so you might want to mention what `-j<n>` in `make` actually does. Also, I recommend not compiling stuff as root - just copy it over afterwards with `sudo`... Do you have this device to test? I am wishing I could upvote but I can't test it myself :(