# HP BS180TX Wifi and Bluetooth not working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, bluetooth, hp, realtek-wireless

I have bought a new HP BS180TX laptop and installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and found that the wifi and bluetooth are not working. Wired connection works fine. I ran `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` and the result I got is

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

What should I do?

**Solved**
The [second answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1018851/217285) resolved my issue.
The first one did not work because the kernel version was not compatible. This even works in Ubuntu 18.04. I have tested this.

Bluetooth issue also fixed by the help of [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033968/how-to-activate-bluetooth-device-for-rtl8723de)

In 18.04, the kernel update can disable wifi. So you will have to redo the steps in the above answer I mentioned to re-enable it.

Comment: @pomsky: Updated.

Comment: It didn't work either. Got an error executing the 5th command.

Comment: Try the other answer, first answer may not work with newer kernels.

Comment: Oh, it worked. I didn't try it because it was not upvoted even once. But now I did. I wanna share that as an answer here. Is that ok?

Comment: I would recommend *not* duplicating an existing answer from Ask Ubuntu itself. Simply "accept" the duplicate by clicking on the button, no harm in that, it would mark your question as a "signpost" to the other question  so that others get directed easily :) Also consider leaving a comment below the answer with your laptop model and kernel version (`uname -r`) saying that this answer worked for you while the other didn't.

Comment: But that doesn't fix the bluetooth.

Comment: @Pilot6: Same here. I did not check it then. If I get a solution I will post here