# How to activate bluetooth device for RTL8723DE?

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, realtek, realtek-wireless

The wireless drivers for the RTL8723DE appeared for downloading and the module is now usable for Wi-Fi.

See [Realtek Semiconductor RTL8723DE Device d723 issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983251/realtek-semiconductor-rtl8723de-device-d723-issue)

But the bluetooth part of it is yet not supported on Ubuntu. How this can be fixed?

`lsusb` shows

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b009 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
```

And `usb-devices | awk '/0bda/' RS=`

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=03 Cnt=01 Dev#=  3 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0bda ProdID=b009 Rev=02.00
S:  Manufacturer=Realtek
S:  Product=802.11n WLAN Adapter
S:  SerialNumber=00e04c000001
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for this bluetooth device had been just added to the 4.17rc kernel.

The code can be easily backported to kernels 4.4 - 4.15. I made a PPA with DKMS packages for `bionic` and `xenial` with the updated `btrtl` module.

It can be installed by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/bluetooth
sudo apt update
sudo apt install btrtl-rtl8723de-dkms
```

You may also need firmware for this device if it is not there. Look into your `/lib/firmware/rtl_bt` directory. If there are no `rtl8723d_config.bin` and `rtl8723d_fw.bin` files, clone the latest `linux-firmware` by

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
```

and get the files from there. It is not that hard. Sorry that I forgot to add the firmware to the package.

The DKMS should survive kernel upgrades.

**Important!:** Ubuntu 18.04 has the `5.3` HWE kernel now. REMOVE this package if you are on 5.3+ kernels. Otherwise BT won't work.

Comment: I still have this issue with kernel 5.4 (firmware installed). Has the support been removed since?

Comment: Kernel 5.4 has the in-tree support.

Comment: How many files should I have in /lib/firmware/rtl_bt/?

Comment: I didn't count them. You need two files for this device.

Comment: this bluetooth module on lenovo l14 seems to be loaded and working as per `systemctl status ...` but can't find any devices. anyone?