# Ubuntu is not detecting RTL8723DE bluetooth adapter on laptop

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, realtek-wireless

I tried many solutions over, for example [How to activate bluetooth device for RTL8723DE?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1033968/480481), but none of them works for me on Ubuntu 16.04.

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb
```

The output of above command:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
    DeviceName: Hanksville Gbe Lan Connection
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1bcf:2c9b Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b009 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: @pomsky I've try this solution https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033968/how-to-activate-bluetooth-device-for-rtl8723de

Comment: please help me!