# RTL8723DE device bluetooth driver

Tags: 18.04, drivers, wireless, bluetooth, realtek-wireless

I have updated to kernel `4.17.0-041700-generic`and installed the Bluetooth driver going through [How to activate bluetooth device for RTL8723DE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033968/how-to-activate-bluetooth-device-for-rtl8723de). In earlier kernel driver it was doing well.

Edit : Now I have installed `5.6.0-050600-generic` and bluetooth is working but wi-fi has gone

`sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6`

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
`cleaning build area......(bad exit status: 2)
make -j2 KERNELRELEASE=5.3.0-46-generic -C /lib/modules/5.3.0-46-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build.........................................(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtlwifi-new: 0.6 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.3.0-46-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/make.log for more information`.

Comment: What is the reasonof installing an unsuported 4.17 mainline kernel, when there is the 5.3 Ubuntu kernel available, that doesn't require any additional drivers. Also the old manual was for kernels that didn't support the module. With new kernels you need to remove any kind of "drivers".

Comment: @Pilot6  Now I have installed 5.6.0-050600-generic and bluetooth is working but wi-fi has gone

Comment: What is the reason of installing random kernels? The 5.6 doesn't support the installed Wi-Fi drivers. If you left the system alone with correct kernel, all would work.

Comment: I answered your BT question. Ask a new one regarding Wi-Fi. Probably the `rtlwifi_new` is too old for the 5.3 kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1033973/167850) carefully, you could have noticed that supported kernels are 4.4-4.15.

You installed for an unknown reason the 4.17 mainline kernel. That's why the module is not building or working.

At present the RTL8723DE bluetooth device is suppored by the 5.3 kernel out of the box. This kernel is preinstalled with Ubuntu 18.04 iso and installable on the initial 18.04 release by

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04
```

Comment: Thanks!! The easiest and effective solution I have found.