# HP laptop, Realtek d732 - No Wifi Adaptor found

Tags: drivers, wireless, realtek

I have a new HP laptop. Ubuntu 18.04 installs fine apart from "No WiFi Adaptor found". I have looked at [Realtek Semiconductor RTL8723DE Device d723 issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983251/realtek-semiconductor-rtl8723de-device-d723-issue) and followed the instructions there ("There is new information on this device"), but get the same error message that others report, namely:

> $ sudo dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
>   Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping... Building
>   module: cleaning build area... 'make' all
>   KVER=4.15.0-22-generic...(bad exit status: 2) ERROR (dkms apport):
>   binary package for rtl8723de: 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
>   not found Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel:
>   4.15.0-22-generic (x86_64) Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/make.log
>   for more information.

I also tried the second suggestion on that page ("You may use the driver hosted at Larry Finger..."). That all installed, but made no difference to "No Wifi Adaptor found".

Here's what the (groovy!) Ubuntu wireless info script says about my setup: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5KNtV5qzzz/

Hoping someone can help.

Comment: Notice it doesn't say kernel module in use: rtl8723de, did you do a dkms remove and uninstall for the first version you tried?

Comment: @pomsky yes I have tried rebooting since then, but see no change.

Comment: @Jeremy31 Clarification: do you suggest I remove dkms and then retry the first answer given at https://askubuntu.com/questions/983251/realtek-semiconductor-rtl8723de-device-d723-issue ?

Comment: Actually is Secure Boot disabled?  Check `mokutil --sb-state`

Comment: @Jeremy31 Secure Boot is enabled.

Comment: Go into BIOS/UEFI settings and disable it so that the module can actually load

Comment: I have done this, but now Ubuntu doesn't boot - it just brings up Windows10.

Comment: @Jeremy31 I don't understand why my disabling Secure Boot messed with Dual Booting into Ubuntu, but it did. So I see two options: I could try to re-enable Secure Boot (doesn't solve the original problem), or could start anew with an Ubuntu iso. Would you agree? Thanks.

Comment: There is a way to sign the module yourself so it will load with secure boot enabled but I haven't tried it