# Realtek Semiconductor RTL8723DE Device d723 issue - problems with the solution

Tags: drivers, apt, kernel, 18.04, realtek

My wifi device Realtek Semiconductor RTL8723DE Device d723 is not recognized by Ubuntu. The solution [Realtek Semiconductor RTL8723DE Device d723 issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983251/realtek-semiconductor-rtl8723de-device-d723-issue)
seems to fit perfectly to my issue, but [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/988947/837067) did not work for me and I do not understand why.

Executing the fourth step, 
`sudo dkms build rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414`,
I get the output

```
Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' all KVER=4.15.0-22-generic...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8723de: 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-22-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/make.log for more information.
```

It seems to me that there is possibly some part of the package missing(?), and this did not get fixed by deleting the files and downloading again (in case the downloaded file was damaged).

I do not know what to do about that issue, as all the solutions I found seem to be some kind of the same, and lead to similar problems for me.

I am an inexperienced user, please tell me if there might be some important information missing.

Comment: The second answer seemed to work, but as I restarted, there still was   "no Wi-Fi Adapter Found" (in the Settings)...  do you have an idea what to do about that?
p.s.: Should I delete this question and ask in the discussion linked above? I did not, as I was not sure how "dead" older discussions are.