# Realtek Semiconductor RTL8723DE Device d723 issue - the solution for Ubuntu 18.04 does not work

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 18.04, realtek-wireless

The problem is well described in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983251/realtek-semiconductor-rtl8723de-device-d723-issue?answertab=active#tab-top).
As the title says, [the suggested fix for the problem](https://askubuntu.com/a/1018851/837067) for Ubuntu 18.04 seems to run fine, and I am relatively sure to meet the requirements, but after executing the steps from that fix, which seemed to work well, there was still "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found" (in the settings. 
I have no idea what to do about that, and the post (respectively the solution quoted above) seemed to fit perfectly to my problem. 
What now?
(p.s.: I was not able to comment the post above due to my very low reputation? Also I tagged this question as version-specific, is it?)

Comment: Just to make sure, did you reboot once after applying the fix?

Comment: Regarding to https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/ubuntu-findet-keine-drahtlosnetzwerke/2/#post-8917818 you should set Secure Boot OFF and 'sudo cp /usr/src/rtlwifi-new-0.6/firmware/rtlwifi/* /lib/firmware/rtlwifi/ '

Comment: I have Secure Boot set OFF and executed the step suggested  by AlexOnLinux, but still there is nothing found. After restarting, of course.