# wireless conectivity problem

Tags: wireless

Till yesterday my Ubuntu 16.04 was working fine. Today when I started my PC it showed this

The system is running in low-graphics mode
your screen,graphics card, and input devices settings could not be detected correctly. You will need to configure these yourself.

After that I had to reinstall Ubuntu.
I was having wifi problem earlier. Enable wifi icon was not showing in the menu. After that I tried running these commands which worked well in the first attempt

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install build-essential dkms git
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8723de.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8723de
sudo dkms build rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
sudo dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
```

I again ran these commands but last 2 commands are giving me this error
Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

```
Building module:
cleaning build area....
'make' all KVER=4.10.0-28-generic.....(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8723de: 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.10.0-28-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/make.log for more information.
```

If I am able to run these two commands then definitely wifi will get working but how to solve this problem?

Comment: The 4.10 kernel hasn't been supported since late January.  Updates should install the 4.13 kernel

Comment: Can you pls tell me how to that upgrade and after upgrading will it work fine. If I am not wrong this repo is yours and there is stated for kernel lower than 4.11.  https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8723de

Comment: Jeremy has two branches there, 4.11 and up and also 4.10 and down.  Although you might be able to build for your 4.10 kernel, I entirely agree that you should update to 4.13 and *then* build the driver.

Comment: And the master branch is 4.11 and up but I don't think it works on 4.15 kernel, for that you should use Larry Fingers rtlwifi_new extended branch.  The 4.13 kernel is only supported for 6 more weeks and then 16.04 will probably switch you to the 4.15 kernel

Comment: See https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de for uninstall directions, then see pomsky answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1018851/300665

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy31. My problem is solved now. I actually did the install from the first link that you provided.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but this issue is solved. I am up with a new issue and I have already asked that as a new question. Pls help me with that