# WiFi adapter not found in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless, 18.04, hp

I have recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 in my hp 15bs 145tu laptop. All packages of Ubuntu seem to be working properly but the WiFi adapter is not found, and I can't connect to the wireless network.

How can I debug/fix this?

Comment: please edit your question and add the output of the wifi-info script. this makes troubleshooting much easier: https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/669014

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of the following command in Terminal: `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`.

Comment: 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev ff), Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci, Kernel modules: ath10k_pci, 6e:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:0116], 0: hci0: Bluetooth Soft blocked: no, Hard blocked: no

Comment: @pomsky I lost wifi adapter when I did a sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade in Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell XPS 13 9370. Above was the result of the command you asked to enter in the terminal.. Could you please help further?

Comment: aah, the answer provided by @varshneydevansh works :)

Comment: For me re installing ubuntu with wired internet connection and selecting 'install required softwares' option in one of the step worked. Tried for 2 days with other solutions but nothing worked.

Comment: sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source

Comment: Hey @Dev, I don't have enough reputation to answer the question so commenting. Remember, this solution involves installing a proprietary driver for Wifi, but it works like a charm. I faced this issue after dual booting Ubuntu 18.0LTS alongside Windows 10, and couldn't find a working solution for months, until today, when I found a working solution. What I did was I opened the "Softwares & Updates" application in Ubuntu, then I switched to "Additional Drivers" tab, then it will show list of proprietary drivers. Install the Wifi driver shown and hopefully WIFI signal will start showing.

Answer (score 14):

First, try to connect with the wired Internet connection (or you can use Mobile Tethering) and use the following commands to install missing Wi-Fi drivers.

Clone the repository (use your Terminal):

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
```

Enter the cloned folder:

```
cd rtlwifi_new
```

Check out the extended branch:

```
git checkout extended
```

Start installation:

```
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de
sudo modprobe rtl8723de
```

That's it! You have now successfully installed the RTL8723de Wi-Fi driver on your Ubuntu 18.04 system. This repo also contains the driver for RTL8723be and much more RealTek devices.

If that doesn't work just go and do this:

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo sed -i '/blacklist bcma/ d' /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
sudo sed -i '/blacklist brcmsmac/ d' /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Reboot. If wifi does not come on, do:

```
sudo modprobe -v brcmsmac
sudo modprobe -v bcma
```

Comment: Why do you think OP has a Realtek device?

Comment: Thanks but i cant found module rtl8723de in rtlwifi_new directory

Comment: Disabling Secure Boot in Bios (Why I enabled it is beyond me except Ubuntu Suggested it in the install),  Nvidia's nvhda wasn't working right and no WiFI, and going into the bios and diasabling it ... rebooting ......  All Wifi is found!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: wifi has gone after the shutdown system.

Comment: I disabled my Fast Boot, it worked and somehow and some days later the Wifi Adapter cannot be found again.......hell...... help~!

Comment: I really don't think you should advice people on installing drivers from random repos.

Comment: For my HP zbook 17 g6 I built and installed the backport of the iwlwifi driver (normally only available on linux kernel 5.1+) using instructions at:

https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi/core_release

Comment: I wouldn't recommend random installation of the drivers. Make sure you check the type using "lspci -nn" and then install specific one.

Comment: @Franva there were similar issues with me . i got my wifi card cleaned up at service centre and its working fine. have you ruled out any hardware involvement ?

Comment: hi @sassy.geek I didn't remember what I did, but I did remember that I bought a shiny new NvME SSD, so I installed the Ubuntu again on the new SSD and it started working