# Ubuntu 18.04 wireless adapter not found on HP

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, hp, adapter

WiFi has stopped working on my computer two days ago. Until that I haven't had any problem with it and it happened suddenly.

My computer is a HP Pavilion 13 x360 from 2014.

I have tried several solutions on internet but none of them worked for me. Some solved it temporaly but when I hibernated my computer and reopen it WiFi wasn't working again. Now WiFi doesn't works even when I try what it solved it before.

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047245/wifi-adapter-not-found-in-ubuntu-18-04) didn't work either.

My output for `lspci` command:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 08)
```

Seems that wireless controller isn't there, and I don't know what to do.

Any idea what could solve this?

**EDIT:**

Here is my `lshw -c network` output:

```
  *-network                 
       descripción: Ethernet interface
       producto: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:09:00.0
       nombre lógico: eno1
       versión: 08
       serie: 6c:c2:17:6e:86:5b
       tamaño: 10Mbit/s
       capacidad: 100Mbit/s
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuración: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-2_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       recursos: irq:19 ioport:3000(size=256) memoria:b2404000-b2404fff memoria:b2400000-b2403fff
  *-network:0 DESACTIVADO
       descripción: Ethernet interface
       id físico: 3
       nombre lógico: virbr0-nic
       serie: 52:54:00:a7:f3:d6
       tamaño: 10Mbit/s
       capacidades: ethernet physical
       configuración: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
  *-network:1
       descripción: Ethernet interface
       id físico: 4
       nombre lógico: lxcbr0
       serie: 00:16:3e:00:00:00
       capacidades: ethernet physical
       configuración: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=10.0.3.1 link=no multicast=yes
  *-network:2
       descripción: Ethernet interface
       id físico: 5
       nombre lógico: virbr0
       serie: 52:54:00:a7:f3:d6
       capacidades: ethernet physical
       configuración: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=192.168.122.1 link=no multicast=yes
  *-network:3
       descripción: Ethernet interface
       id físico: 6
       nombre lógico: docker0
       serie: 02:42:e4:96:48:1b
       capacidades: ethernet physical
       configuración: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
  *-network:4
       descripción: Ethernet interface
       id físico: 7
       nombre lógico: br-2c754fe6c808
       serie: 02:42:e0:1f:0f:ab
       capacidades: ethernet physical
       configuración: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.18.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
```

Also sometimes wireless connection works. One time it was working I captured this commands:

**lspci**:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
08:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev ff)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 08)
```

**ifconfig**

```
br-3e16b20b6485: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.23.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.23.255.255
        ether 02:42:ce:2d:2f:00  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-b4f85ba125f5: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255
        ether 02:42:22:77:05:a8  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-ca5b6b9b884d: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.22.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.22.255.255
        ether 02:42:52:68:5f:27  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-e99fb540f27c: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.19.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.19.255.255
        ether 02:42:33:86:c6:dd  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:ca:77:6a:ef  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eno1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 6c:c2:17:6e:86:5b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 10940  bytes 982163 (982.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 14238  bytes 1150158 (1.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Bucle local)
        RX packets 5270  bytes 362984 (362.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5270  bytes 362984 (362.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lxcbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.3.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        ether 00:16:3e:00:00:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:a7:f3:d6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlo1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:ee:65:b6:b8:f1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 26  bytes 4644 (4.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 198  bytes 24594 (24.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**Another one**

```
eno1      no wireless extensions.

br-e99fb540f27c  no wireless extensions.

br-b4f85ba125f5  no wireless extensions.

docker0   no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lxcbr0    no wireless extensions.

virbr0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

br-3e16b20b6485  no wireless extensions.

virbr0-nic  no wireless extensions.

br-ca5b6b9b884d  no wireless extensions.
```

I tried installing this repository: https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de.git

But it didn't work. I think I should blacklist the actual adapater in the `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file, but I don't know what I should add there.

Here is my `sudo ls /etc/modprobe.d/`

```
alsa-base.conf
amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf
blacklist-ath_pci.conf
blacklist.conf
blacklist-firewire.conf
blacklist-frambuffer.conf
blacklist-mode.conf
blacklist-oss.conf
blacklist-rare-network.conf
blacklist-watchdog.conf
dkms.conf
intel-microcode-blacklist.conf
iwlwifi.conf
qemu-system-x86.conf
rtl8723be.conf
```

**Note that it got installed rtl8723be instead of rtl8723de**

And I added this to `blacklist.conf` file

```
blacklist acer_wmi
blacklist bcma/ d
blacklist brcmsmac/ d
blacklist iwlwifi
blacklist dkms
```

Btw I'm my hp with a single boot, I have only Ubuntu 18.04 installed on it.

Comment: Do you have dual boot with Windows ? If yes, then check your WIFI in windows that it's enabled. Sometimes when the WIFI in windows is disabled, it causes problems in Ubuntu.

Comment: No sir, I had my computer dual booted but 5 months ago I changed my hard disk for a new SSD and I only have Ubuntu on it. After the disk change all was working perfectly btw, so that can't be the problem

Comment: @MitKan Forgot to mention you

Comment: post the output of sudo lshw -c network, and check this post, it seems like most HP Laptops have problems with the drivers on Linux ---->>>   http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/08/no-wifi-adapter-found-hp-laptops-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: @MitKan I edited the post with new information which could be relevant