# Hp Omen 15-dc1052nr ubuntu 18.04 no wifi adapter found

Tags: 18.04, wireless, hp

I have recently bought `HP Omen 15-dc1052nr` and installed Ubuntu 18.04 alongside already installed windows 10. But after installing ubuntu when I go to `settings -> Wi-Fi`, it shows `No Wi-Fi Adapter found`. I have searched internet alot and even follow this answer too https://askubuntu.com/a/1050793/996118 but I am unable to use Wi-Fi on my device.

Information regarding my system can be seen by visiting this link https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/skbCCQnykM/