# No Wi-Fi adapter found on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04

Today I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a brand new computer and while installation went smooth, I can't connect to the Internet via WiFi. Firstly, I just thought it is a matter of enabling the WiFi manually, so I went to the settings and saw a notice: "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found". I did some googling and tried to perform all the steps described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1050793/1016115), but it still doesn't work.

The `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` command returns:

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] [8086:a370] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0034]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi, wl
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

And `lshw -C network` returns:

```
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlp0s20f3
       version: 10
       serial: 0c:dd:24:2c:af:83
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.0.0-23-generic firmware=43.95eb4e97.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:b4518000-b451bfff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: enp7s0
       version: 15
       serial: 98:fa:9b:a0:b0:cc
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b4304000-b4304fff memory:b4300000-b4303fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: enp0s20f0u2
       serial: 12:7f:41:92:a5:de
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.47 link=yes multicast=yes
```

What can I do more to make things work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf <<< "blacklist ideapad_laptop"
```

and reboot.

**Explanation:**

As you can see the wireless device is "hardware blocked" by `rfkill`.

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

New Ideapad laptops don't have a hardware wireless switch, and the `ideapad_laptop` kernel module considers a switch to be off.

So we disable the module, and Wi-Fi works.

Kernel developers add new laptop models to a list that need a quirk for the module. But new models appear faster than they are added.

If you are interested, you can send a patch upstream ;-)

Comment: You can also remove `bcmwl-kernel-source`, because it is not needed for Intel.

Comment: +1. Nice and simple :-)

Comment: And as usual no explanation as to what you're doing or why. Where does an Ideapad laptop enter into things, considering the user made no mention of the type of computer used?

Comment: @PaulBenson I explained this a number of times. Added one here.