# No WiFi Adapter Found on Dell Vostro 5481-7273 in 18.04.3

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, dell-vostro

**I think it is solved: I loaded the prior kernel version in GRUB, and now WiFi works fine.**

I was checking emails in 18.04.3 LTS on my [Dell Vostro 5481-7273 laptop](https://www.dell.com/support/search/us/en/04#q=Vostro%205481-7273) and noticed a strange symbol I've never seen before, near the WiFi symbol.

I clicked on it to find "location services" are turned off. I went to settings, found "location services" there are 'in use'. Then I saw web pages didn't load.

I turned the WiFi off, turned it back on, and it didn't find any WiFi network. I rebooted the laptop, and found the "location services" icon disappeared; It's off per the settings. No WiFi adapter was found.

I tried [WiFi adapter not found in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047245/wifi-adapter-not-found-in-ubuntu-18-04) and [Unable to get wifi adapter working - clean 19.04 install - network unclaimed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156167/unable-to-get-wifi-adapter-working-clean-19-04-install-network-unclaimed)

I don't know what else should I post that may help....

sudo lshw -C network:

```
*-network                 
   description: Network controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 14.3
   bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
   version: 30
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
   resources: irq:16 memory:a131c000-a131ffff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: enp1s0
   version: 15
   serial: e4:54:e8:0b:ee:1d
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8169 latency=0 multicast=yes
   resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a1204000-a1204fff memory:a1200000-a1203fff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 2
   logical name: enp0s20f0u1
   serial: 1a:e9:9f:94:ab:ee
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.27 link=yes multicast=yes
```

rfkill list:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
```

nmcli device show wlan0:

```
Error: Device 'wlan0' not found.
```

sudo lshw -short -class network

```
H/W path       Device       Class          Description
======================================================
/0/100/14.3                 network        Intel Corporation
/0/100/1d/0    enp1s0       network        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
/2             enp0s20f0u1  network        Ethernet interface
```

Comment: May be it just broke. I'd open the case, check the wireless card, and then look for a replacement.

Comment: Your English, as is almost always the case with folks who apologize for it, is excellent. Please run the wireless-info script explained at https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/197910 , click [edit], and put its results at the end of your question. It scouts out your hardware, for you could have four different WiFi cards per Dell's documentation: Intel Wireless-9462 802.11AC 1x1 Wi-Fi + BT V5.0 Wireless Card, Intel Wireless-9560 802.11AC 2x2 Wi-Fi + BT V5.0 Wireless Card, Dell Qualcomm QCA9377 (DW1810), or Dell Qualcomm QCA61x4A (DW1820).

Comment: @K7AAY I've loaded Ubuntu with the previous kernel and now everything works fine as always, so can I call it the solution of this problem and is there any way how to mark my post as "solved"?

Comment: Yes, but I hope you write up an answer below and accept it, then file a bug report on the kermel + your WiFi adapter. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs