# How to permanently install WiFi driver Realtek 8723DE in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, realtek

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my brand-new (2019) HP 15-da1005dx laptop, in dual boot with Windows 10. Unfortunately, ubuntu 18 does not support the Realtek 8723 Wi-Fi adapter, so when Ubuntu starts I get the "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found" warning and only ethernet wired connection is allowed. I installed the drivers and obtained Wi-Fi connection for a few months ([WiFi adapter not found in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047245/wifi-adapter-not-found-in-ubuntu-18-04)), first with weak signal and then with a decent signal after reading and following MANY linux forums posts like this one (https://connectwww.com/how-to-solve-realtek-rtl8723be-weak-wifi-signal-problem-in-ubuntu/4625/). However, for some reason the driver stops working periodically and the "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found" warning reappears. I suspect this happens due to automatic system updates, but I'm not sure. Anyway, this last time I can't find a way to fix the problem.

Here I copy some relevant info:

- **inxi -SMNxxz:**

System:    Host: jdc-hp Kernel: 5.0.0-36-generic x86_64 bits: 64 gcc: 7.4.0
           Desktop: Gnome 3.28.4 (Gtk 3.22.30-1ubuntu4) dm: gdm3
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Machine:   Device: laptop System: HP product: HP Laptop 15-da1xxx v: Type1ProductConfigId serial: N/A
           Mobo: HP model: 8532 v: 70.31 serial: N/A
           UEFI: Insyde v: F.21 date: 07/25/2019
           Chassis: type: 10 serial: N/A

Network:   Card-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCIE Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           driver: r8169 port: 4000 bus-ID: 01:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:8168
           Card-2: Realtek Device d723
           port: 3000 bus-ID: 02:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:d723

- I installed kernell>5 for some reason: **uname -r** = 5.0.0.36-generic
- **dkms status**: rtl8723de, 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414, 5.0.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) #I have installed and removed different drivers and evend dkms purge but keep getting the same warning
- **iwconfig**: eno1/lo  no wireless extensions
- **sudo modprobe rtl8723de**: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8723de': Operation not permitted

Comment: What does `sudo modprobe <your driver name>` say?

Comment: modprobe: FATAL: Module rlt8723de not found in directory /lib/modules/5.0.0-36-generic

Comment: Try repeating the compilation of your module (make sure you have the `linux-headers` for your kernel.)

Comment: Done:apt search linux-headers-$(uname -r)
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
linux-headers-5.0.0-36-generic/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 5.0.0-36.39~18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  Linux kernel headers for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I managed to solve the problem by doing the following:

1) In the BIOS boot options disabled the Secure Boot option.

2) Remove and reinstall the driver with these commands:

```
sudo dkms remove rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414 --all
sudo dkms add ./rtl8723de
sudo dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
```

3) At this point a UEFI Secure Boot configuration window pops up. Generate a Machine-Owner Key (MOK). Then follow with reboot:

```
sudo depmod -a
reboot
```

4) When reebooting, a blue screen appeares to confirm the change using the previously generated MOK. Select the "Enroll MOK" option and enter the key.

After reboot I have WiFi connectivity in Ubuntu 18 again. In my previous attemps to install this driver I was not aware of this MOK option. Hope this time the driver keeps installed permanently. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:
1. `git clone https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de.git -b 5.0-up`

2. `dkms add ./rtl8723de 
   dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414`
3. `depmod -a`
4. `reboot`.

More information could be found at https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de

Comment: I tried this before and I just repeated it, but it didn't work.

Comment: (base) jdc@jdc-hp:~$ sudo dkms add ./rtl8723de
Error! DKMS tree already contains: rtl8723de-5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.
(base) jdc@jdc-hp:~$ sudo dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
Module rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414 already installed on kernel 5.0.0-36-generic/x86_64

Comment: Then, try doing the uninstall part and installing again.

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled the driver using `dkms remove driver/version --all` and `dkms install driver/version`. The UEFI system asked me to generate a password, and when booting a blue screen appeared, I guess it's something from the secure boot (which is enable). However it was not necessary to use this new password. I still don't get WiFi but at least **dkms status** no longer returns any warning.

Comment: Secure Boot DOES NOT allow the easy installation of module outside of `apt` way. You shall disable the secure boot to allow this unsigned module to work.