# Realtek RTL8723BE Wireless card Does not work in Ubuntu18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, drivers, wireless, realtek

I am having HP laptop (Hp 15R250Tu) with **Realtek RTL8723BE** WIFI card. The WIFI connection keeps getting Dropped after some time like 15-20 minutes and then it won't connect no matter what I do expect the only option left is to restart. To solve this I tried several solutions but NO Success. After trying this solutions I am getting WIFI-Adapter not found and its Not getting connected. I don't know whether I messed up with my WIFI drivers. I am left further with No Clue what shall be done. Please any help would be appreciated.

Solutions tried up till now:

[realtek-rtl8723be-wifi-drivers-not-working-after-upgrading-to-5-4-0-37](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1249902/realtek-rtl8723be-wifi-drivers-not-working-after-upgrading-to-5-4-0-37)

[realtek-rtl8723be-wi-fi-incredibly-weak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883673/realtek-rtl8723be-wi-fi-incredibly-weak)

[how-to-permanently-install-wifi-driver-realtek-8723de-in-ubuntu-18-04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1197560/how-to-permanently-install-wifi-driver-realtek-8723de-in-ubuntu-18-04)

[wifi-signal-is-weak-in-ubuntu-18-04-with-rtl8723be](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058379/wifi-signal-is-weak-in-ubuntu-18-04-with-rtl8723be)

[wifi-networks-not-found-ubuntu-18-04-with-rtl8723be](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069153/wifi-networks-not-found-ubuntu-18-04-with-rtl8723be)

[how-do-i-get-a-realtek-rtl8723be-wireless-card-to-work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/how-do-i-get-a-realtek-rtl8723be-wireless-card-to-work)

[unable-to-connect-wifi-ubuntu-14-04-lts-hp-pavilion-network-driver-rtl8723be](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645220/unable-to-connect-wifi-ubuntu-14-04-lts-hp-pavilion-network-driver-rtl8723be/729660#729660)

Edit 1: As per comments
`dkms status`

```
fwts-efi-runtime-dkms, 18.03.00, 5.3.0-59-generic, x86_64: installed
fwts-efi-runtime-dkms, 18.03.00, 5.3.0-61-generic, x86_64: installed
rtlwifi-new, 0.10: added
rtlwifi-new, 0.6, 5.3.0-59-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
```

`dmesg | grep -i rtl`

```
[    4.660507] r8169 0000:04:00.0 eth0: RTL8106e, 5c:b9:01:f9:a3:62, XID 449, IRQ 93
[   29.093217] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: HCI_OP_READ_LOCAL_VERSION failed (-110)
[   50.560829] RTL8208 Fast Ethernet r8169-400:00: attached PHY driver [RTL8208 Fast Ethernet] (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-400:00, irq=IGNORE)
```

`rfkill list`

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
```

Edit 2:

1. Output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list

   0: hci0: Bluetooth
   Soft blocked: yes
   Hard blocked: no
2. Output of dmesg | grep -i rtl

   [    4.666458] r8169 0000:04:00.0 eth0: RTL8106e, 5c:b9:01:f9:a3:62, XID 449, IRQ 93

   [   18.379865] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723

   [   18.381299] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1

   [   18.381305] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin

   [   20.016261] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin

   [   20.016311] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin failed with error -2

   [   20.016327] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz -2, total sz 22496

   [   49.864307] RTL8208 Fast Ethernet r8169-400:00: attached PHY driver [RTL8208 Fast Ethernet] (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-400:00, irq=IGNORE)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Anyway all is looking good there. What is the kernel version `uname -a`?

Comment: Ok I'll remember from next time @Pilot6 Even I followed your previous answers. Kernel Version is 5.3.0-61 updated yesterday.

Comment: Please add output AS TEXT of `dkms status` and `dmesg | grep -i rtl` and `rfkill list`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `rtlwifi_new` modules. They are not needed with the 5.3 kernel. Run in a terminal:

```
sudo dkms remove rtlwifi-new/0.10 --all
sudo dkms remove rtlwifi-new/0.6 --all
```

and reboot.

Comment: Followed the commands and rebooted nothing is shown up still Wifi adapter not found.

Comment: Please add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` and `dmesg | grep -i rtl`.

Comment: I have updated the post with the outputs

Comment: Can you format text properly? It is unreadable. I don't see any wireless adapters now. The device is disabled in BIOS or broken.

Comment: Sorry Sir I edited it but don't know why the changes was not visible  I have edited once again.

Comment: Anyways to fix it