# Realtek RTL8723BE Wireless card not working in Ubuntu18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, kernel, realtek

I have an HP laptop (Hp 15R250Tu) with **Realtek RTL8723BE** WIFI card after upgrading the kernel to 5.4.0-45 generic. The WIFI connection keeps getting Dropped after some time like 15-20 minutes with message **Activation of network connection failed** and then it won't connect no matter what I do expect the only option left is to restart. Sometimes it won't at all show Wifi option in menu just the Airplane mode is active on toggling it to off the Bluetooth gets on this keeps on going but WIFI doesn't show up. Even I opened up the laptop to swap the antenna wire to(aux port/no.2) and to my surprise there is ***no second antenna port*** at all given in wifi card. so all and all the antenna depends on just single connection and this leaves no room to swap the antenna port. Further I tried Live boot strange to see but even the *live boot is not showing wireless option* I tried both Linux mint and Manjaro.This issue is persistent from many months tried several solutions Larry finger git hub branch, Dkms but not successful.

Questions Referred

1. [realtek-rtl8723be-wifi-drivers-not-working-after-upgrading-to-5-4-0-37](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1249902/realtek-rtl8723be-wifi-drivers-not-working-after-upgrading-to-5-4-0-37)
2. [realtek-rtl8723be-wi-fi-incredibly-weak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883673/realtek-rtl8723be-wi-fi-incredibly-weak)
3. [how-to-permanently-install-wifi-driver-realtek-8723de-in-ubuntu-18-04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1197560/how-to-permanently-install-wifi-driver-realtek-8723de-in-ubuntu-18-04)
4. [wifi-signal-is-weak-in-ubuntu-18-04-with-rtl8723be](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058379/wifi-signal-is-weak-in-ubuntu-18-04-with-rtl8723be)
5. [wifi-networks-not-found-ubuntu-18-04-with-rtl8723be](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069153/wifi-networks-not-found-ubuntu-18-04-with-rtl8723be)
6. [how-do-i-get-a-realtek-rtl8723be-wireless-card-to-work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/how-do-i-get-a-realtek-rtl8723be-wireless-card-to-work)
7. [unable-to-connect-wifi-ubuntu-14-04-lts-hp-pavilion-network-driver-rtl8723be](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645220/unable-to-connect-wifi-ubuntu-14-04-lts-hp-pavilion-network-driver-rtl8723be/729660#729660)

Output from terminal

**uname -r**

> 5.4.0-45-generic

**dkms status**

```
fwts-efi-runtime-dkms, 18.03.00, 5.4.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed
fwts-efi-runtime-dkms, 18.03.00, 5.4.0-45-generic, x86_64: installed
```

**dmesg | grep -i rtl**

```
[    4.788890] r8169 0000:04:00.0 eth0: RTL8106e, 5c:b9:01:f9:a3:62, XID 449, IRQ 93
[   23.139091] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723
[   23.140085] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[   23.140088] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[   23.479730] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin
[   23.479782] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin failed with error -2
[   23.479798] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz -2, total sz 22496
[   24.298711] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0x0e2f9f73
[   61.320543] RTL8208 Fast Ethernet r8169-400:00: attached PHY driver [RTL8208 Fast Ethernet] (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-400:00, irq=IGNORE)
[ 2294.012286] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723
[ 2294.014441] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[ 2294.014458] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[ 2294.014544] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin
[ 2294.102350] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin failed with error -2
[ 2294.102409] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz -2, total sz 22496
[ 2294.995873] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0x0e2f9f73
[ 2314.407626] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723
[ 2314.409564] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[ 2314.409578] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[ 2314.409671] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin
[ 2314.409809] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin failed with error -2
[ 2314.409860] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz -2, total sz 22496
[ 2315.249387] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0x0e2f9f73
[ 2322.273698] RTL8208 Fast Ethernet r8169-400:00: attached PHY driver [RTL8208 Fast Ethernet] (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-400:00, irq=IGNORE)
[ 2335.384040] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723
[ 2335.385039] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[ 2335.385044] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[ 2335.540042] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin
[ 2335.540104] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin failed with error -2
[ 2335.540138] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz -2, total sz 22496
[ 2335.868705] RTL8208 Fast Ethernet r8169-400:00: attached PHY driver [RTL8208 Fast Ethernet] (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-400:00, irq=IGNORE)
[ 2336.393069] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0x0e2f9f73
```

**rfkill list**

```
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

**iwconfig**

```
enp4s0    no wireless extensions.

enp0s29u1u2  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

**modinfro rtl8723be**

```
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8723be/rtl8723be.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723befw_36.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin
description:    Realtek 8723BE 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         PageHe  <page_he@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     775916BF393FDE315ED454E
alias:          pci:v000010ECd0000B723sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl8723-common,rtl_pci,btcoexist,mac80211
```

**journalctl** link [here](https://pastebin.com/DAahggA0)
**dmesg** link [here](https://pastebin.com/e54kb2yF)
**lspci** [here](https://pastebin.com/tfYt1Wzq)
**wireless info txt** [here](https://pastebin.com/CQ2e4mdE)

**EDIT 1:**
**dkms status**

```
fwts-efi-runtime-dkms, 18.03.00, 5.4.0-45-generic, x86_64: installed
fwts-efi-runtime-dkms, 18.03.00, 5.4.0-47-generic, x86_64: installed
```

**sudo lshw -C network**

```
*-generic DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Illegal Vendor ID
       vendor: Illegal Vendor ID
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: ff
       serial: c4:8e:8f:af:99:7b
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: bus_master vga_palette cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=5.4.0-47-generic firmware=N/A latency=255 link=no maxlatency=255 mingnt=255 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:90700000-90703fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 07
       serial: 5c:b9:01:f9:a3:62
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:19 ioport:1000(size=256) memory:90500000-90500fff memory:90400000-90403fff
```

Comment: Ping me with a comment that starts with @heynnema

Comment: Re-seating the modem card brought it back to life. Now `modinfo rtl8723be | grep -i parm` and look for the antenna switching parm.

Comment: @heynnema currently I have not set any parameters still the WIFI is strong and up I will check this thoroughly and will give the updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the chat, and comments...

We removed the modem/bluetooth card from its socket, and re-inserted it, and now the modem is working again. Signal is strong.

Use `modinfo rtl8723be | grep -i parm` to see any available parameter settings.

Comment: Sir I am extremely sorry for late reply was out of station for few days. The wifi is working but still sometime the issue arises and signal gets dropped.

Comment: @Tushar Does `dkms status` show any output? Edit your question and show me any output... also `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: Right now the airplane mode is ON the wifi is not detected.

Comment: @Tushar Can you turn off airplane mode? Go ahead and show me the two commands.

Comment: @Tushar Here's the clue. The `lshw` command shows "Illegal Vendor ID". I suspect that the card needs reseating... only this time... clean the gold contacts with Isopropyl alcohol... or... the card may be defective.

Comment: @Tushar Clean the gold contacts, as I mentioned, but, while the contacts are still wet, re-insert the card and wiggle it around, so as to clean the contacts in the socket. Wait for it to dry before powering on the computer.

Comment: I will do this I was trying to get wifi connected but it didn't I tried multiple times. Shall we discuss the further conversation here or in chat section.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113263/discussion-between-heynnema-and-tushar).