# Bluetooth not working Ubuntu 18.04 Realtek

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, realtek-wireless

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 on HP 240 G7 and bluetooth is not working. Says "no adapters found" and the switch is grayed out.

[image: bt config]

These are some command outputs I've run:

```
~$ sudo lsusb | grep Bluetooth
```

```
~$ sudo lshw
*-usb:3 NO RECLAMADO
                   descripción: Interfaz Bluetooth
                   producto: 802.11n WLAN Adapter
                   fabricante: Realtek
                   id físico: 8
                   información del bus: usb@1:8
                   versión: 2.00
                   serie: 00e04c000001
                   capacidades: bluetooth usb-1.10
                   configuración: driver=btusb maxpower=500mA speed=12Mbit/s
```

```
~$ dmesg | grep -i blue
[   15.090310] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   15.090323] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   15.090326] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   15.090327] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   15.090329] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   68.342346] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   68.342350] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   68.342361] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

```
~$ service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-01-22 11:18:05 -03; 15min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 2616 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─2616 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

ene 22 11:18:05 javo-PC systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
ene 22 11:18:05 javo-PC bluetoothd[2616]: Bluetooth daemon 5.48
ene 22 11:18:05 javo-PC systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
ene 22 11:18:05 javo-PC bluetoothd[2616]: Starting SDP server
ene 22 11:18:05 javo-PC bluetoothd[2616]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
```

```
~$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723de
    Kernel modules: rtl8723de
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:b009 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b67f Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2717:003b  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2717:ff40  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
~$ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# power on
No default controller available
[bluetooth]# list
[bluetooth]# exit
Agent unregistered
```

```
~$ usb-devices | awk '/0bda/' RS=
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=07 Cnt=03 Dev#=  5 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0bda ProdID=b009 Rev=02.00
S:  Manufacturer=Realtek
S:  Product=802.11n WLAN Adapter
S:  SerialNumber=00e04c000001
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=(none)
```

```
~$ modinfo btrtl
filename:       /lib/modules/5.3.0-26-generic/updates/dkms/btrtl.ko
license:        GPL
version:        0.1.1
description:    Bluetooth support for Realtek devices ver 0.1.1
author:         Daniel Drake <drake@endlessm.com>
srcversion:     0C8563E53114EC0065BFC6F
depends:        bluetooth
retpoline:      Y
name:           btrtl
vermagic:       5.3.0-26-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
```

```
~$ dkms status
btrtl-rtl8723de, 0.1~bionic, 5.3.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed
```

I've tryed every possible solution I found but nothing works. I even turned off/on the bluetooth in BIOS. What else can I do?

EDIT AFTER ANSWER

Now bluetooth keeps telling it's off even if I turn it on.
[image]

```
~$ modinfo btrtl
filename:       /lib/modules/5.3.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btrtl.ko
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8822b_config.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8822b_fw.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8821a_config.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8821a_fw.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8761a_config.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8761a_fw.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8723ds_config.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8723ds_fw.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8723bs_config.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8723bs_fw.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8723a_fw.bin
license:        GPL
version:        0.1
description:    Bluetooth support for Realtek devices ver 0.1
author:         Daniel Drake <drake@endlessm.com>
srcversion:     6E762C4F4D6D9CCD2330B10
depends:        bluetooth
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           btrtl
vermagic:       5.3.0-26-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
```

```
~$ dmesg | grep -i blue
[   13.976836] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   13.976848] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   13.976851] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   13.976852] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   13.976854] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   14.040014] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rtl: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=000d lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=8723
[   14.040950] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=2
[   14.040951] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723d_fw.bin
[   14.110936] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723d_config.bin
[   14.131570] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz 10, total sz 33266
[   16.286682] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc20 tx timeout
[   24.446900] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: download fw command failed (-110)
[   28.351691] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   28.351692] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   28.351696] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[ 1439.093176] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1001 tx timeout
[ 1447.285126] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: HCI_OP_READ_LOCAL_VERSION failed (-110)
[ 4942.483816] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1001 tx timeout
[ 4950.611136] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: HCI_OP_READ_LOCAL_VERSION failed (-110)
[ 6825.302438] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1001 tx timeout
[ 6833.430252] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: HCI_OP_READ_LOCAL_VERSION failed (-110)
```

```
~$ rfkill list
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: What is the kernel version `uname -a`?

Comment: Linux javo-PC 5.3.0-26-generic #28~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 18 16:40:14 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Hm. It should work with this kernel.  Please add output of `usb-devices | awk '/0bda/' RS=`

Comment: Added to post at the bottom.

Comment: That's a mystery. There is `{ USB_VENDOR_AND_INTERFACE_INFO(0x0bda, 0xe0, 0x01, 0x01),
   .driver_info = BTUSB_REALTEK },` in `btusb.c` but `btusb` is not loading.

Comment: What if you run `sudo modprobe btusb`?

Comment: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'btusb': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)

Comment: [25017.149985] btusb: Unknown symbol btrtl_shutdown_realtek (err -2)

Comment: I can suggest to report it as a bug by `ubuntu-bug linux`. You can try a mainline kernel like 5.4 and test if the bug is there.

Comment: Did you install any drivers? Maybe that is the reason. Please add output of `modinfo btrtl`. I didn't see problems with this device.

Comment: Also please add `dkms status`.

Comment: Before this, I had the same issue with wifi so I did this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047245/wifi-adapter-not-found-in-ubuntu-18-04 without need to purge bcmwl-kernel-source.

Comment: You don't need any external drivers with the 5.3 kernel. You need to uninstall them all.

Comment: I've done some things and this has change a bit. May I get some help again?

Answer (score 1):

You neet to remove the 3rd-party module that you installed.

Kernel has updated to 5.3 and it breaks BT.

Run in a terminal

```
sudo apt purge btrtl-rtl8723de-dkms
```

and reboot.

If the package is not found, run

```
sudo dkms remove btrtl-rtl8723de/0.1~bionic --all
```

This was installed from my PPA. Remove it too by

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:hanipouspilot/bluetooth
```

I backported the `btrtl` from the 5.3 kernel to let people use the BT on older kernels. No need any more now.

Comment: I did this and wifi isn't lost, but bluetooth still doesn't work. Now ths switch isn't greyed out but turning it on does nothing.

Comment: Did it uninstall the driver or there was an error?

Comment: No error. Uninstalled ok.

Comment: Added new screenshot.

Comment: Screenshots are useless. What is the log now? What does modifo show? What `dkms status` show?

Comment: `dkms status` shows nothing, and `modinfo btrtl` shows what I edited.

Comment: Now its much better. One last effort. `dmesg | grep -i blue`. It looks there is no firmware.

Comment: And also `rfkil list`

Comment: Added both command outputs.

Comment: This looks like a bug to me now. Errors in loading the firmware. Report it to Launchpar by running `ubuntu-bug linux`. It used to work on older kernels with my module. The've broken something now. Another way is to return to 4.15 and use my module. Post the `dmesg | grep -i blue` to the report and explain that BT doesn't work. It works for other people with the same device though.