# Ethernet not showing on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, windows, 18.04, ethernet

I switched from windows 10 to ubuntu on my laptop(hp 15-bw085nd) and I don't have an ethernet connection or a wifi connection.
When I use ifconfig -a it only shows my loopback.
Maybe it has something to do with the drivers, can someone please let me know what to do?

lspci output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1576
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Carrizo (rev c8)
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini HDMI/DP Audio
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157b
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157c
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157c
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157b
00:03.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157c
00:08.0 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1578
00:09.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157d
00:09.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157a
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 20)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 49)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 49)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 4a)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1570
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1571
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1572
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1573
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1574
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1575
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d723
05:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445] (rev ff)
```

Comment: These are two questions. Regarding Wi-FI see https://askubuntu.com/questions/983251/realtek-semiconductor-rtl8723de-device-d723-issue

Comment: Regarding Ethernet you need `r8168-dkms`. Or maybe you are not connected well. Some revisions of this adapter need a driver, most of them don't.