# Ubuntu 18.04 RTL8723BE WiFi not working

Tags: wireless, 18.04, realtek-wireless

Recently I installed Ubuntu 18.04. Unfortunately my WiFi adapter is not working properly. it couldn't detect the low range WiFi signals.

Output of `lshw -C network`

```
*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 74:df:bf:81:e7:a7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.15.0-32-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.43.81 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1100000-b1103fff
```

Comment: sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager (can help, not sure ... )

Comment: Please edit your question and include the output of `lshw -C network`.

Comment: Is it an external wifi adapter? If yes, can you give us the type of your adapter?

Comment: no, its inbuilt one @damadam

Comment: That's a known issue with Realtek 8723. Try [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1018851/816190). It helped me to get the WiFi to work flawlessly on two of my friends' laptop.