# Particular Wifi network is not getting connected to Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, internet

I have Ubuntu 16.04LTS (dual boot with Win 10 ) installed on my Laptop. Initially there was no wifi driver pre-installed(Although Wired connection was there but no wireless). So I installed Realtek "rtl8723de" wifi driver from git repository[Repository Name: rtlwifi_new ] (according to the wifi card which is there on my laptop, I checked this through Device Manger in Windows). Now wifi is working fine. I can connect to my mobile hotspot's network or my friends hotspot network. But I can't connect to HP network ( my hostel's wifi network, open network). Also this HP network works fine in windows. I mean I can easily connect to HP when using windows. So what should I do ???

I have tried restarting the network manager by giving command

```
    sudo service network-manager restart
```

Also after executing the command

```
    sudo modprobe rtl8723de
```

No error is flagged. 
Here's the output of the command

```
    sudo lshw -class network
```

Output:

```
network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: enp1s0
   version: 15
   serial: 48:ba:4e:ae:07:dd
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:34 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:d3304000-d3304fff memory:d3300000-d3303fff
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 00
   serial: d4:6a:6a:0a:6c:15
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723de driverversion=4.15.0-29-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:44 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:d2000000-d200ffff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 2
   logical name: enp0s18u1u1
   serial: 62:ec:4d:94:9e:34
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.226 link=yes multicast=yes
```

Hope this output helps!

I searched on internet regarding this issue but coudln't find any answers. So what I should do ? Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Realtek Semiconductor RTL8723DE Device d723 issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983251/realtek-semiconductor-rtl8723de-device-d723-issue)