# WiFi is enabled but I get "Device is not ready" with rtl8723de

Tags: wireless, realtek-wireless

[image: Wifi Enable but Device not ready]

Output of `lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 15
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b1104000-b1104fff memory:b1100000-b1103fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: f8:da:0c:00:cc:2b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723de driverversion=4.15.0-38-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:131 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1000000-b100ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: enp0s20f0u3
       serial: ca:36:16:27:bf:5f
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.112 link=yes multicast=yes
```

**A link to WiFi details**:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/FtNV8jxrGr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HP needs the very latest drivers for rtl8723de.

First, try booting to a Ubuntu 18.04.1 DVD/USB, and see if the wireless works. If it does, then you'll need to upgrade your OS. If it doesn't work, then see the following links for a driver that should work... with a little effort...

**https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new**

```
If you are looking for the driver for rtl8822be or rtl8723de, then execute the following command:

git checkout origin/extended -b extended

Installation instruction

You can find <> using lspci | grep Wireless. Afterwards, execute the following lines of codes in your shell:

You will need to install "make", "gcc", "kernel headers", "kernel build essentials", and "git".

If you are running Ubuntu, then

 sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git

Please note the first paragraph above.

For all distros:
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -r <<YOUR WIRELESS DRIVER CODE>>
sudo modprobe <<YOUR WIRELESS DRIVER CODE>>

#### Option configuration
If it turns out that your system needs one of the configuration options, then do the following:

vim /etc/modprobe.d/<<YOUR WIRELESS DRIVER CODE>>.conf 

There, enter the line below:
`options <<YOUR WIRELESS DRIVER CODE>> <<driver_option_name>>=<value>`
```

**https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2367405&page=11**

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r)
git clone -b extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
sudo cp /usr/src/rtlwifi-new-0.6/firmware/rtlwifi/* /lib/firmware/rtlwifi/
```

And searching for rtl8723de, here on AU, will find a few more posts of interest, like such...

**[Realtek Semiconductor RTL8723DE Device d723 issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983251/realtek-semiconductor-rtl8723de-device-d723-issue)**

Comment: Thank you . I installed latest driver and it start working. thanks again