# No wifi on Xubuntu with RTL8723DE

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, realtek-wireless

I just recently installed Xubuntu on my laptop alongside Windows 10. I can't find a way to search for Wi-Fi connections as it doesn't give the option. I looked around online, but I didn't find anything that worked.

I had to connect to ethernet to run update and upgrade commands, but it still won't search for Wi-Fi.

`rfkill`

```
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked
```

`ifconfig`

```
enp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.168  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 fe80::7b5c:dc97:d535:2eee  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether e4:e7:49:a0:71:51  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 11585  bytes 8686420 (8.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7977  bytes 1095167 (1.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1751  bytes 178413 (178.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1751  bytes 178413 (178.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Intel(R) 100 Series Chipset Family LPC Controller/eSPI Controller - 9D4E (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d723
```

`mokutil --sb-state`

```
SecureBoot enabled
```

**edit:**

I turned off secure boot. While the advice here is certainly helping, the issue is not completely resolved. But I'm seeing the wi-fi pop in and out.

After turning off secure boot, I got the Wi-Fi option, but it's popping in and out. It's not staying on. When I do see the available wi-fi option, and I click on it, it starts to load showing a spinning circle, and then goes away and turns back into an up arrow and down arrow **↑↓**

sudo lsmod

```
Module                  Size  Used by
ccm                    20480  0
bnep                   20480  2
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
arc4                   16384  2
rtl8723de              98304  0
btcoexist             434176  1 rtl8723de
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
phydm_mod             856064  1 rtl8723de
snd_hda_codec_realtek   106496  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
wmi_bmof               16384  0
hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
intel_wmi_thunderbolt    16384  0
rtl8723_common         24576  1 rtl8723de
rtl_pci                32768  1 rtl8723de
uvcvideo               86016  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_core         40960  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
videodev              184320  3 videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
media                  40960  2 videodev,uvcvideo
intel_rapl             20480  0
snd_soc_skl            90112  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
snd_soc_skl_ipc        65536  1 snd_soc_skl
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
i915                 1617920  4
snd_hda_ext_core       24576  1 snd_soc_skl
coretemp               16384  0
snd_soc_sst_dsp        32768  1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
kvm_intel             212992  0
kvm                   598016  1 kvm_intel
snd_soc_sst_ipc        16384  1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
snd_soc_acpi           16384  1 snd_soc_skl
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
snd_soc_core          241664  1 snd_soc_skl
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
snd_compress           20480  1 snd_soc_core
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_intel          40960  3
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
pcbc                   16384  0
snd_hda_core           81920  7 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_skl
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                98304  8 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_soc_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
aesni_intel           188416  0
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
intel_cstate           20480  0
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
rtlwifi               163840  5 rtl_pci,rtl8723de,btcoexist,phydm_mod,rtl8723_common
mac80211              778240  2 rtl_pci,rtlwifi
input_leds             16384  0
joydev                 24576  0
serio_raw              16384  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
snd                    81920  19 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
btintel                16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             548864  12 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
soundcore              16384  1 snd
processor_thermal_device    16384  0
mei_me                 40960  0
cfg80211              622592  2 rtlwifi,mac80211
drm_kms_helper        172032  1 i915
ecdh_generic           24576  1 bluetooth
mei                    90112  1 mei_me
shpchp                 36864  0
intel_soc_dts_iosf     16384  1 processor_thermal_device
drm                   401408  5 drm_kms_helper,i915
intel_pch_thermal      16384  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
wmi                    24576  3 hp_wmi,intel_wmi_thunderbolt,wmi_bmof
int3403_thermal        16384  0
int340x_thermal_zone    16384  2 int3403_thermal,processor_thermal_device
video                  45056  1 i915
int3400_thermal        16384  0
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
mac_hid                16384  0
acpi_pad              180224  0
hp_wireless            16384  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  6
parport_pc             36864  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ip_tables              28672  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                40960  2
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
psmouse               147456  0
r8169                  86016  0
ahci                   40960  4
mii                    16384  1 r8169
libahci                32768  1 ahci
i2c_hid                20480  0
hid                   118784  3 i2c_hid,usbhid,hid_generic
```

Comment: `iconfig` and `ifconfig` are two separate commands, you did not use the correct command as was requested.  Also include the output of `lspci` on your system as well.

Comment: What result from terminal for `mokutil --sb-state`

Comment: The output said SecureBoot enabled

Comment: Ask Ubuntu is a question-and-answer site, posts need to follow the proper format. So please remove your solution from the question and post it as an answer below by clicking the 'Answer your question' button. It's absolutely fine (and very much encouraged) to [self-answer your question](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer). Also remove "Update" and "Solved" from the title.

Comment: Initially you had SecureBoot enabled. Then after installing the driver you had an issue with low signal strength. Both the issues are covered here: [Installing Wi-Fi driver for Realtek Semiconductor RTL8723DE Device](https://askubuntu.com/q/983251/480481)

Answer (score 2):

Go into your BIOS, and disable SecureBoot. Save and exit.

In `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` I added the line:

```
blacklist ideapad_laptop
```

If you just want to test this as a solution, do:

```
sudo rmmod ideapad_laptop
```

I think you will find networks are available immediately. This worked on Ubuntu 18.10 why is the kernel module named `ideapad_lenovo` and not a more logical "realtek-something-or-other"? I have no idea, [ask Linus](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/platform/x86/ideapad-laptop.c).

Comment: I disabled secureboot, as I explained in the edit above.

However, to clarify, am I to replace "laptop" with the laptop I have, as you also mentioned "ideapad_lenovo"? Typing "ideapad_laptop" gave me: `rmmod: ERROR: Module ideapad_laptop is not currently loaded`

Comment: I too am learning to troubleshoot faulty modules in linux. can you do `sudo lsmod` and list results?

Comment: I listed the output above.

Answer (score 2):

I tried reinstalling Ubuntu, and and gave the solutions here another try. They did not work, however I did find a solution that worked. I'll leave a link here for anyone that would have this issue, and would stumble across this post.

I did searches around for hp 17-by0021dx and RTL8723DE. I'd add the tags for both, but I can't.

https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Wireless-and-Networking/Realtek-8723DE-wifi-module-amp-Bluetooth-Linux-driver/td-p/6477307

**From the link (I followed the second option):**

> **For installing from git sources in Ubuntu:**
>
> Either download a ".zip" copy of the git sources for RTL8723DE driver
>   from https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/archive/extended.zip ,
>   extract it and follow step (2) below
>
> OR
>
> 1. Make sure you have git installed. You can install git using apt install git or through synaptic/software manager. If you want to use
>      dkms to make and install the driver, make sure that dkms also is
>      installed. You can download and install using below commands, in a
>      terminal:
>
>    :~$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install git dkms
> 2. The RTL8723DE driver is in the git extended branch. So,
>
> Open a terminal:
>
> ```
> :~$ cd Downloads
>
> :~$ git clone -b extended --single-branch https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
> unofficial
> :~$ cd rtlwifi_new
>
> Now, either you can run:
> :~/Downloads/rtlwifi_new$ make 
> :~/Downloads/rtlwifi_new$ sudo make install
>
> OR use dkms to build and manage the modules:
>
> :~/Downloads/rtlwifi_new$ sudo dkms add ../rtlwifi_new
> :~/Downloads/rtlwifi_new$ sudo dkms build rtlwifi-new/0.6 
> :~/Downloads/rtlwifi_new$ sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
> :~/Downloads/rtl-new/rtlwifi_new$ sudo modprobe -v rtl8723de ant_sel=2
> ```
>
> ^^ That should work. If firmware error is shown, reboot and will work.
>   Make sure, you have linux-headers for the respective kernel(s) and
>   build-essential packages installed.
>
> For me, ant_sel=2 shows the maximum WiFi signal gain. So, I've added
>   below lines in a separate conf file:
>
> ```
> :~$ sudo /bin/sh -c 'echo "options rtl8723de ant_sel=2" >> /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf'
> ```
>
> Hope this helps. If it does not build, use :
>
> ```
> :~/Downloads/rtlwifi_new$ sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6 --force
> ```

---

<sub>Source: posted by OP as [an update to the question](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1130423/7) itself</sub>