# RTL8723DE weak Wi-Fi signal

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless

I recently bought a HP-BW088AX Laptop from Amazon. I initially installed Kali Linux on it because I wanted to learn penetration testing and hacking, but as I was new to Linux I decided to go for a more user-friendly distro. So I dual booted my laptop with Ubuntu.

After I installed Ubuntu I had to face some issues with the inbuilt wireless card. I had faced similar issues with Kali Linux but I got them solved.

The problem was that the OS wasn't detecting the inbuilt wireless card which is a Realtek RTL8723DE chipset. I installed the drivers for it from here [RTL8723DE Drivers](https://ibcomputing.com/how-to-install-wifi-driver-for-rtl8723de/), consequently the wireless card was detected but the signal was very weak.
 So I started finding a solution on the internet and I found this : 
[Weak Wi-Fi Signal in Ubuntu](https://www.techkhedut.com/wifi-signal-strength-low-ubuntu-18-04-linux/)

Output of lspci:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d723
```

This solution worked for Kali Linux which is also a debian based distro but the same is not working for Ubuntu. But it is not working in Ubuntu.
Everything works fine until I run this command :

```
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723de ant_sel=2
```

I get the following output :

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module ant_sel=2 not found.
```

I didn't face this issue in Kali Linux.

- I have Ubuntu 18.04.02 LTS.
- Processor : AMD® A9-9420 radeon r5, 5 compute cores 2c+3g × 2
- Graphics : AMD® Stoney
- GNOME : 3.28.2

Any help would be appreciated a lot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de && sudo modprobe rtl8723de ant_sel=2`

Comment: Use the driver from Larry Finger's repo for newer Ubuntu releases with a newer kernel. Possible duplicate of [Realtek Semiconductor RTL8723DE Device d723 issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983251/realtek-semiconductor-rtl8723de-device-d723-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drivers for RTL8723DE were released recently on github. Visit this link and : [RTL8723DE drivers](https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de)

and clone the folder.

Follow the instructions using root privilages:

```
git clone https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de.git -b 4.15-up
dkms add ./rtl8723de
dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
depmod -a
reboot
```