# Ubuntu wifi rtl8723de not working after upgrade to 18.04LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 18.04, realtek

```
nishanthr@vision:~$ lspci -v | grep -i network  
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d723
```

[Installing Wi-Fi driver for Realtek Semiconductor RTL8723DE Device [10ec:d723]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983251/realtek-semiconductor-rtl8723de-device-d723-issue)
I had already tried this when I had 16.04LTS and now when I'm trying again it says

```
nishanthr@vision:~$ git clone -b extended --single-branch
https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git fatal: destination path
 'rtlwifi_new' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

Then I did this

```
cd rtlwifi_new/ && git checkout origin/extended -b extended   
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de  
sudo modprobe rtl8723de
```

Also tried

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source  
sudo sed -i '/blacklist bcma/ d' /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf   
sudo sed -i '/blacklist brcmsmac/ d'/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

And tried changing antenna

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de && sleep 5 && sudo modprobe rtl8723de ant_sel=X (X=1,2)
```

and rebooted several times and still not working.

Comment: It's not clear to me that you cleared out the build with the previous kernel version.  In the project directory you need to `make clean` and then `make` and then `make install`.

Comment: So you're telling me to do this in rtlwifi_new directory?

Comment: From your question, I have the idea that you are installing using the same directory as you used for the previous kernel. If so you can go into that and execute a `git pull`. This will refresh the code but you still need to run the clean. With a kernel change we often have to rebuild our drivers and the build must be a new build with all the previous build artifacts removed.

Comment: All the commands I ran and executed where in same directory,I did install it in the same directory as I did for my previous kernel. Now what do I do ?

Comment: Please edit your question to include all the commands you ran, or if the list you give is complete, then please run the commands I suggest.