# Bionic Beaver does not recognize wifi adapter

Tags: networking, wireless

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS on my HP laptop model 15-da0012dx. Ubuntu is not recognizing the internal wifi adapter. Settings says "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found".

This thing does have an internal wifi adapter; I formerly used it with the preinstalled OS. HP describes it as "802.11b/g/n (1x1) Wi-Fi® and Bluetooth® 4.2 combo". (full mfg specs at https://support.hp.com/gb-en/document/c05997533

**Action:** 
    lspci -v | grep -i network

**Expected:**
    list of all network adapters including wifi

**Result:**

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d723
```

**Action:** lspci -knn | grep Net -A3

**Result:**

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
```

**Action:**
    nmcli d status

**Result:**
    DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION
    eno1    ethernet  connected  Wired connection 1 
    lo      loopback  unmanaged  --

**Action:**
    lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net

**Result:**

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:84a6]
    Kernel driver in use: r816
    Kernel modules: r8169
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
```

**Action:**
    sudo lshw -C network

**Result:**

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 15
       serial: 10:62:e5:c8:e8:f1
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.8 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b1104000-b1104fff memory:b1100000-b1103fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1000000-b100ffff
```

**Action:**
    lspci

**Result:**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Intel(R) 100 Series Chipset Family LPC Controller/eSPI Controller - 9D4E (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d723
```

**Action:**
    Installed drivers from the rtlwifi_new git as instructed at askubuntu.com/questions/9832511
    Restarted

**Result:**

```
Still no wifi.
```

**Action:**
    sudo lshw -C network

**Result:**

```
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 15
       serial: 10:62:e5:c8:e8:f1
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.8 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b1104000-b1104fff memory:b1100000-b1103fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1000000-b100ffff
```

**Action:**
    sudo modprobe rtl8723de && dmesg | grep rtl

**Result:**

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8723de': Operation not permitted
```

**Action:**

```
rfkill list all
```

**Result:**

```
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**Action:**
    Disabled secure boot

**Result:**

Wifi works

**Action:**
    sudo lshw -C network

**Result:**

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 15
       serial: 10:62:e5:c8:e8:f1
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.8 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b1104000-b1104fff memory:b1100000-b1103fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 80:c5:f2:d7:70:27
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723de driverversion=4.18.0-25-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:130 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1000000-b100ffff
```

Comment: Can you add the outputs to the question. As is, there is not enough info to help you.

Comment: Please edit the question to include results for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net`  But I would guess https://askubuntu.com/a/1018851/300665 will fix it

Comment: Looks like RTL8723de: https://askubuntu.com/questions/983251/realtek-semiconductor-rtl8723de-device-d723-issue. Still unsupported.

Comment: I see. The Realtek d723 is the wifi adapter in this machine.

Comment: [askubuntu.com/questions/983251](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983251/realtek-semiconductor-rtl8723de-device-d723-issue) lists a solution: install drivers from the rtlwifi_new git. However, that didn't work for me. I installed the drivers per the instructions and restarted, but Settings still says there is no Wifi adapter. @mikewhatever

Comment: Is the device still shown as Unclaimed in `lshw`? Is there any clue in the log? Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe rtl8723de && dmesg | grep rtl` Also: `rfkill list all`

Comment: Go into UEFI/BIOS settings and disable Secure Boot, leave the Secure Boot keys alone

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:
1. Installed drivers from the rtlwifi_new git as instructed at https://askubuntu.com/a/1018851/300665.
2. Shut down Ubuntu, went into the UEFI BIOS config page, and disabled secure boot, as recommended in the comments.
3. Started Ubuntu and tested wifi. Works great.

**Before:**

```
sudo lshw -C network
    ...
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1000000-b100ffff
```

**After:**

```
sudo lshw -C network
    ...
      *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 80:c5:f2:d7:70:27
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723de driverversion=4.18.0-25-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:130 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1000000-b100ffff
   ...
```

This seems like a nonoptimal solution, because I had to disable secure boot.

Thanks to everyone who responded!