# Unable to detect wifi networks in ubuntu 16.04 Realtek Semiconductor RTL8723DE device issue, their is a check mark on Enable wifi but no wifi networks

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek

I am facing problem in detecting wifi networks, I have already gone through all the steps explained in Realtek Semiconductor RTL8723de device d723 issue. It helped and their is a check mark on enable wifi at the top right corner, but the laptop is unable to detect any network.

Kindly Help I will be greatful to you.

Comment: Did you try the `ant_sel` parameter? See the end of this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/983251/realtek-semiconductor-rtl8723de-device-d723-issue

Comment: yes I tried that too

Comment: Both =1 and =2 with no improvement? If yes, then check here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180 Paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: yeah both =1 and =2 but no improvement, I am checking it

Comment: I did what you said

Comment: Where is the link to the paste?

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/FZkMRTkJkM/

Comment: Above is the link

Comment: "To connect to raw.githubusercontent.com insecurely, use --no-check-certificate." Please do: `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 --no-check-certificate https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info

Comment: done! here is the link https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/qNgdJ6W5t9/

Comment: "Results saved in /home/mayur/wireless-info.txt". <--That is what we need pasted. Running the script is trivial; seeing the *results* of running the script is where the useful information lies.

Comment: ohh! sorry, I am doing it

Comment: Ok done! Here is the link https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7pGMCv5QFv/

Comment: You have a file: `/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf` which says: `options rtl8723de ant_sel=3` 3 is not an available option. Please change it to 2, reboot and tell me if the device now scans: sudo iwlist wlo1 scan` Also let us see: `dmesg | grep rtl` All at: http://paste.ubuntu.com Please reboot with the ethernet temporarily disconnected so that Network Manager doesn't default to ethernet.

Comment: Everything what you said is here. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/J4fthWMXJ8/

Comment: And Yes, I made ethernet connection temporarily off, It was unable to scan the networks. even after selecting antenna two. Here is the wireless-info.txt updated file https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2f3gjS3mcR/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your paste, we see:

> rtl8723de 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for
>   rtlwifi/rtl8723defw.bin failed with error -2

Let's install the needed firmware and reboot. From the terminal:

```
cd /lib/firmware/rtlwifi
sudo wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/raw/extended/firmware/rtlwifi/rtl8723defw.bin
```

Reboot and tell us if the wireless is working.

Comment: firmware not installed I think. Please check https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/nmJ3mr3PPP/

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: YeSSSS!!!!!!, Now its working Thankyou so much

Comment: Woo hoo! Glad it's working! Have fun.