# Realtek 8723de on Linux Kernel 5.3

Tags: networking, drivers, compiling, realtek-wireless, dkms

Using an HP 245 G6 laptop with AMD A9 APU and Realtek 8723de wireless running Ubuntu 19.04.

To resolve an issue with the laptop being unable to resume from suspend properly (AMDGPU crashing on resume) I've manually installed Linux kernel 5.3 (rc6 currently - I found some info on the issue I was having here https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1704792).

However I can't install the driver for the Wi-Fi from https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git on kernel 5.3 - any ideas on how to get this working in the newer kernel would be appreciated.

Specifically, during the rtlwifi install, after running:

```bsh
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

I get:

```
Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area....
make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=5.3.0-050300rc6-generic -C /lib/modules/5.3.0-050300rc6-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build.............(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtlwifi-new: 0.6 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.3.0-050300rc6-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/make.log for more information.
```

The log at `/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/make.log` contains:

```
DKMS make.log for rtlwifi-new-0.6 for kernel 5.3.0-050300rc6-generic (x86_64)
Mon Sep  2 14:42:59 NZST 2019
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-050300rc6-generic'
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/btcoexist/halbtc8192e2ant.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8188ee/dm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/halmac/halmac_api.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_debug.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/halmac/halmac_88xx/halmac_api_88xx_usb.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8188ee/fw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/btcoexist/halbtc8723b1ant.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/halmac/halmac_88xx/halmac_api_88xx_sdio.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_antdiv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8188ee/hw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_soml.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/halmac/halmac_88xx/halmac_api_88xx.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/btcoexist/halbtc8723b2ant.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_smt_ant.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8188ee/led.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_interface.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/btcoexist/halbtc8821a1ant.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/halmac/halmac_88xx/halmac_api_88xx_pcie.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8188ee/phy.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_phystatus.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/halmac/halmac_88xx/halmac_func_88xx.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/btcoexist/halbtc8821a2ant.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_hwconfig.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8188ee/pwrseq.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/btcoexist/halbtc8822b1ant.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/halmac/halmac_88xx/halmac_8822b/halmac_api_8822b_pcie.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8188ee/rf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8188ee/sw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/halmac/halmac_88xx/halmac_8822b/halmac_func_8822b.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_dig.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/btcoexist/halbtc8822b2ant.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8188ee/table.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/halmac/halmac_88xx/halmac_8822b/halmac_api_8822b_sdio.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8188ee/trx.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_pathdiv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/halmac/halmac_88xx/halmac_8822b/halmac_api_8822b.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8188ee/rtl8188ee.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_rainfo.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192c/main.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/halmac/halmac_88xx/halmac_8822b/halmac_8822b_phy.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/btcoexist/halbtc8822bwifionly.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192c/dm_common.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_dynamictxpower.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/halmac/halmac_88xx/halmac_8822b/halmac_8822b_pwr_seq.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/btcoexist/halbtc8723d1ant.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_adaptivity.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192c/fw_common.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/halmac/halmac_88xx/halmac_8822b/halmac_api_8822b_usb.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/halmac/rtl_halmac.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/btcoexist/halbtc8723d2ant.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_cfotracking.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192c/phy_common.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_noisemonitor.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/halmac/halmac.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ce/dm.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192c/rtl8192c-common.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192cu/dm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_dfs.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ce/hw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/btcoexist/halbtcoutsrc.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192cu/hw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_adc_sampling.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/btcoexist/rtl_btc.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ce/led.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_ccx.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/btcoexist/btcoexist.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192de/dm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ce/phy.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192cu/led.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_psd.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192cu/mac.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ce/rf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192de/fw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_primary_cca.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ce/sw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192cu/phy.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192de/hw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_cck_pd.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ce/table.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ce/trx.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192cu/rf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_rssi_monitor.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ce/rtl8192ce.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ee/dm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192de/led.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192cu/sw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_auto_dbg.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192de/phy.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192cu/table.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_math_lib.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192cu/trx.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ee/fw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_api.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192cu/rtl8192cu.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192se/dm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ee/hw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_pow_train.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192se/fw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192de/rf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/halrf/halrf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192se/hw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ee/led.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192de/sw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ee/phy.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192de/table.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/halrf/halphyrf_ce.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192de/trx.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192se/led.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/halrf/halrf_powertracking_ce.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192de/rtl8192de.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723ae/dm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192se/phy.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ee/pwrseq.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/halrf/halrf_powertracking.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723ae/fw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ee/rf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/halrf/halrf_kfree.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192se/rf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723ae/hal_btc.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ee/sw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/halrf/rtl8822b/halrf_8822b.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192se/sw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ee/table.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ee/trx.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723ae/hal_bt_coexist.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192se/table.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/halrf/rtl8822b/halrf_iqk_8822b.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192se/trx.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723ae/hw.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ee/rtl8192ee.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723be/dm.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192se/rtl8192se.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723com/main.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/rtl8822b/halhwimg8822b_bb.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723com/dm_common.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723be/fw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/rtl8822b/halhwimg8822b_mac.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723ae/led.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723com/fw_common.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723be/hw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/rtl8822b/halhwimg8822b_rf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723ae/phy.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723com/phy_common.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723ae/pwrseq.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723com/rtl8723-common.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/rtl8822b/phydm_hal_api8822b.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723de/fw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723be/led.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723ae/rf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723be/phy.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723de/hw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/rtl8822b/phydm_regconfig8822b.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723ae/sw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/rtl8822b/phydm_rtl8822b.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723ae/table.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723ae/trx.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723be/pwrseq.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723de/led.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/rtl8723d/halhwimg8723d_bb.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723ae/rtl8723ae.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8821ae/dm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723be/rf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723de/phy.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/rtl8723d/halhwimg8723d_mac.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723be/sw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8821ae/fw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/rtl8723d/halhwimg8723d_rf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723de/pwrseq.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723be/table.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723be/trx.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723de/rf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/rtl8723d/phydm_regconfig8723d.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8821ae/hw.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723be/rtl8723be.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8822be/fw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723de/sw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/rtl8723d/phydm_rtl8723d.o
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8821ae/hw.c: In function ‘_rtl8821ae_mrate_idx_to_arfr_id’:
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8821ae/hw.c:3453:8: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
    ret = 7;
    ~~~~^~~
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8821ae/hw.c:3454:2: note: here
  case RATR_INX_WIRELESS_AC_5N:
  ^~~~
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/halrf/rtl8723d/halrf_8723d.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723de/table.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8822be/hw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723de/trx.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8821ae/led.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/rtl_phydm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8821ae/phy.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723de/rtl8723de.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/base.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8822be/led.o
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8821ae/phy.c: In function ‘_rtl8812ae_phy_set_rfe_reg_24g’:
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8821ae/phy.c:389:6: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
   if (rtlpriv->btcoexist.bt_coexistence) {
      ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8821ae/phy.c:397:2: note: here
  case 0:
  ^~~~
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_mod.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8822be/phy.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/cam.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/debug.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8822be/sw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8821ae/pwrseq.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/efuse.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/ps.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8822be/trx.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8821ae/rf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rc.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/regd.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8822be/rtl8822be.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/stats.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8821ae/sw.o
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rc.c: In function ‘rtl_get_rate’:
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rc.c:191:6: error: implicit declaration of function ‘rate_control_send_low’; did you mean ‘rate_control_set_rates’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  if (rate_control_send_low(sta, priv_sta, txrc))
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      rate_control_set_rates
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:281: /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8821ae/table.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8821ae/trx.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8821ae/rtl8821ae.o
make: *** [Makefile:1624: _module_/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-050300rc6-generic'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Wi-Fi driver for Realtek Semiconductor RTL8723DE Device \[10ec:d723\]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983251/installing-wi-fi-driver-for-realtek-semiconductor-rtl8723de-device-10ecd723)

Comment: Kernel 5.3 natively supports this adapter. No drivers are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem in Ubuntu 19.10. I fixed it by doing apt update, apt upgrade and apt autoremove.

**You must have an internet connection**

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y && sudo apt autoremove
```

From here you can follow the steps from http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/04/nstall-rtl8723de-wifi-driver-ubuntu-19-04/, which would basically be:

In the folder where you have rtlwifi_new directory:

```
rm -rf rtlwifi_new && git clone -b extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
```

Now there is only the build:

```
sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new && sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

Comment: That worked when I tested it again. Although I'm not sure exactly why, it might be because I'm using the newly released 5.3 kernel instead of the 5.3 rc6?

Answer (score 0):

I have followed below steps to solve this issue with HP 15-bs1xx Laptop runs Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver) with '5.3.0-26-generic' version of Linux kernel.

Checkout and build rtl wifi code:

```
git clone -b extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git

make && sudo make install
```

Add '/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf' configuration to load module on startup and dual antena support. Conf file content is below,

```
options rtl8723de ant_sel=2
```

Insert module with below command

```
sudo modprobe rtl8723de
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
git clone https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de.git -b current
dkms add ./rtl8723de
dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
depmod -a
reboot
```