# USB Wifi RTL8812AU does not work

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb, iwlwifi

On a fresh install of Ubuntu 19.10 5.3.0-29-generic. I have an RTL8812AU USB wifi that I would rather use instead of onboard AC7260. The LED on the RTL8812AU does not come on.

What I tried:

- Blacklisted the onboard AC7260 through blacklist.conf.
- Have installed the latest RTL8812AU ver 5.6.4.2.
- Have rebooted with AC7260 blacklisted and without.
- Tried other USB ports.
- It works on Windows.
- I unplugged RTL8812AU, re-installed it through remove.sh, install.sh and plugged back.

> sudo lshw -C network :

```
*-network                 
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 7260
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: bb
   serial: 7c:5c:f8:50:96:d2
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.3.0-29-generic firmware=17.3216344376.0 ip=192.168.2.54 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:130 memory:dfe00000-dfe01fff

*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.6
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
   logical name: enp0s31f6
   version: 31
   serial: d0:50:99:85:4e:6d
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.8-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:128 memory:dff00000-dff1ffff
```

> lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list:

```
   02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev bb)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:4070]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
   0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
   1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

> lsusb (device 002 is the RTL8812AU) :

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

> dkms status

```
rtl8812au, 5.1.5, 5.3.0-29-generic, x86_64: built
rtl8812au, 5.6.4.2, 5.3.0-29-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `modinfo 8812au | grep B812` When you get no result, we shall conclude that 8812au is incorrect for your device. Hint: https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959 Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Followed your link and the LED came on. And it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working.

Answer (score 0):

This driver solved my problem for 19.10

https://github.com/gordboy/rtl8812au

Answer (score -1):

Try this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983251/installing-wi-fi-driver-for-realtek-semiconductor-rtl8723de-device-10ecd723) which might help you with your question. The link helped me get my internal modem working again. I had to
 remove my DKMS and reinstall it again since I had the wrong software.

Comment: He has no rtl8723de device.His usb.id is not 10ec:d723 as you can see above.