# WiFi, Network and Bluetooth not work in Xubuntu for Hp Notebook

Tags: networking, xubuntu, hp

Study ALL possible solutions but none works.  I download packages and drivers to my mobile phone and transfer them to my laptop.
I'm very frustrated.
Can anybody help me?
Thanks.

EDIT 1: Thank you Pilot6 for you answer. This is some results:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:    bionic


$ sudo lshw -c network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 15
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fea04000-fea04fff memory:fea00000-fea03fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fe900000-fe90ffff


$ sudo modprobe rtl8723
modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8723 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.3.0-40-generic


$ lspci | grep -i realtek
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d723
```

I tried the following:
1) lwfinger/rtlwifi_new github's package
2) mrizkimaulidan/rtlwifi_new github's package
2) smlinux github's package
3) fintecheando github's package 
4) tomaspinho/rtl8821ce github's package
And so on.

EDIT2: Thank you again Pilot6. The solution of your link not resolve my problem. It's the result of your request:

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
    Kernel modules: rtl8723de, 8723de

$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: What is th Xubuntu version? Please elaborate "not work". Which packages did you download? Please [edit] the question and add details.

Comment: What you tried is all wrong. You have an `rtl8723de` wireless device. So installing Intel drivers, or some other crap couldn't help.

Comment: The correct way is to install `rtlwifi_new` https://askubuntu.com/a/1018851/167850 What's wrong with that? Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

The `rtl8723de` and `8723de` can't load.

There maybe a problem with having both modules, but start with that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I remember the problem. Initially, I could not boot the system. I fix this problem. But one requirement it was activate "Security mode". This is why reason by which it was activated. Anyway, at this moment I can't boot in "5.0.0-40-generic" kernel, but i can boot in "5.0.0-37-generic".