# Can't connect to wifi in linux ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, wireless, kernel, rtl

I am new to Ubuntu and Linux.  I replaced Windows with Ubuntu 18.04 on my HP laptop, with WiFi chip RTL8723DE.

I have already fixed a problem with an error saying "WiFi adapter not found".  I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1235988) answer and [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1018851/1096951) answer to solve that problem.

Now I can interact with WiFi, but after rebooting the PC, even though I can scan and see WiFi networks, when I try to connect, I get the error: `activation of network connection failed`

I am a novice using Ubuntu/Linux and I don't have Windows anymore.  Please help me find a solution or help direct me to resources.  I don't know where to start searching.

Comment: the correct answer for new kernel is https://askubuntu.com/a/1250296/167850. But you need to remove all you installed before.

Comment: @Pilot6 yes I tried that also
there are 2 problems: first I don't know how to uninstall old drivers(coming from windows I never worked this low-level with the machine before) and second I tried that answer also but I get error in the terminal when I make install command, thanks for your reply hope you could guide me

Comment: There is a folder called modprobe.d in /etc I understand that it contains configuration information about network devices, and I don't know if I also messed it up from some command in the terminal

Comment: It is too hard to fix all you could mess up.

Comment: So there is no solution? :(

Comment: There is always a solution to do a fresh install and install drivers correctly. Also there is a solution to analyze what you really did and revert it. This needs some time and effort.

Comment: @Pilot6 magically your answer here https://askubuntu.com/a/1250296/1096951 solved the problem, I don't know or care why it didn't work before but now it worked, and I hope  it doesn't break after a while like other answers did, thanks alot