# Ubuntu 20.04: I cannot compile latest ndiswrapper

Tags: networking, ndiswrapper

I have installed an Ubuntu 20.04 and I cannot found any working driver for `0bda:d723 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11n WLAN Adapter`.

So I decided to use a windows driver, but when I install ndiswrapper by apt install, modprobe is not worked for me (it cannot find a ndiswrapper module). After that I have removed the installed ndiswrapper by apt remove.

Later I 've tried to download ndiswrapper and install by make install, but it gives me a compile error:

```
home/tomi/ndiswrapper-1.63/driver/loader.c: In function ‘load_sys_files’:
/home/tomi/ndiswrapper-1.63/driver/loader.c:157:4: error: too many arguments to function ‘__vmalloc’
  157 |    __vmalloc(load_driver->sys_files[i].size,
      |    ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from ./include/asm-generic/io.h:911,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/io.h:375,
                 from ./include/linux/scatterlist.h:9,
                 from ./include/linux/dma-mapping.h:10,
                 from ./include/linux/skbuff.h:31,
                 from ./include/net/net_namespace.h:39,
                 from ./include/linux/netdevice.h:37,
                 from /home/tomi/ndiswrapper-1.63/driver/ntoskernel.h:25,
                 from /home/tomi/ndiswrapper-1.63/driver/ndis.h:19,
                 from /home/tomi/ndiswrapper-1.63/driver/loader.c:16:
./include/linux/vmalloc.h:105:14: note: declared here
  105 | extern void *__vmalloc(unsigned long size, gfp_t gfp_mask);
      |              ^~~~~~~~~
make[4]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:288: /home/tomi/ndiswrapper-1.63/driver/loader.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [Makefile:1849: /home/tomi/ndiswrapper-1.63/driver] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.11.0-43-generic'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:183: modules] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/tomi/ndiswrapper-1.63/driver'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:186: ndiswrapper.ko] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/tomi/ndiswrapper-1.63/driver'

make: *** [Makefile:27: install] Error 2
```

How can I use ndiswrapper from ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Wi-Fi driver for Realtek Semiconductor RTL8723DE Device \[10ec:d723\]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983251/installing-wi-fi-driver-for-realtek-semiconductor-rtl8723de-device-10ecd723) No, you can't use ndiswrapper, itwas abandoned a long time ago (and never worked properly anyway).

Comment: In your link, the first answare has an invalid link: github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git gives http 404 error