# 0bda:d723 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11n WLAN Adapter not works in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, ubuntu-drivers

I have installed an Ubuntu 20.04 on umax notebook and I cannot found any working driver for `0bda:d723 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11n WLAN Adapter`.

lsusb shows me the device, but I cannot found any wifi network adapter

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:6310 Microdia Sonix USB 2.0 Camera
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:d723 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0751 Genesys Logic, Inc. microSD Card Reader
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05c6:f00e Qualcomm, Inc. Redmi 9T
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I have tried ndiswrapper but it not worked for me: [Ubuntu 20.04: I cannot compile latest ndiswrapper](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1382363/ubuntu-20-04-i-cannot-compile-latest-ndiswrapper)

I have tried other solutions from here (with similar wifi card): [Installing Wi-Fi driver for Realtek Semiconductor RTL8723DE Device [10ec:d723]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983251/installing-wi-fi-driver-for-realtek-semiconductor-rtl8723de-device-10ecd723)

- https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git is not exists
- https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8723de.git gives compile error:

```
    sudo dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
    
    Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...
    
    Building module:
    cleaning build area...
    'make' all KVER=5.11.0-43-generic...(bad exit status: 2)
    ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8723de: 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414 not found
    Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.11.0-43-generic (x86_64)
    Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/make.log for more information.
    tomi@tomi-Visionbook-14Wr:~$ cat /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/make.log
    DKMS make.log for rtl8723de-5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414 for kernel 5.11.0-43-generic (x86_64)
    2021. dec. 29., szerda, 10:56:39 CET
    make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.11.0-43-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build  modules
    make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.11.0-43-generic'
      CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_cmd.o
    In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/osdep_service.h:42,
                     from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/drv_types.h:32,
                     from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
    /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/osdep_service_linux.h: In function ‘_init_timer’:
    /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/osdep_service_linux.h:287:8: error: ‘_timer’ {aka ‘struct timer_list’} has no member named ‘data’
      287 |  ptimer->data = (unsigned long)cntx;
          |        ^~
    /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/osdep_service_linux.h:288:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_timer’; did you mean ‘_init_timer’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
      288 |  init_timer(ptimer);
          |  ^~~~~~~~~~
          |  _init_timer
    In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/drv_types.h:35,
                     from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
    /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/wifi.h: At top level:
    /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/wifi.h:1006: warning: "IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF" redefined
     1006 | #define IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF 0x40
          | 
    In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/osdep_service_linux.h:86,
                     from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/osdep_service.h:42,
                     from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/drv_types.h:32,
                     from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
    ./include/linux/ieee80211.h:1657: note: this is the location of the previous definition
     1657 | #define IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF  0x100
          | 
    cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
    make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:288: /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [Makefile:1849: /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.11.0-43-generic'
    make: *** [Makefile:1884: modules] Error 2
```

Is there any working driver in ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Why negative vote?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tried several other drivers previously, this assumes that you have installed all of the prerequisites.

With a working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git
cd rtw88
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtw_8723de
```

You will need to disable Secure Boot.

This driver must be reinstalled every time that Update Manager offers a newer kernel version. After the requested reboot, with a temporary internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, do:

```
cd rtw88
make clean
git pull
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtw_8723de
```

Your wireless should be working again. Please retain the rtw88 file and these instructions for that time.

Comment: seems not to be working, I see a following message in my journalctl: `rtw_core: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel`

Comment: Be certain that Secure Boot is disabled and show us: `sudo dmesg | grep rtw` Did you try a reboot?

Comment: I have disabled secure boot and rebooted my computer. Output of the command:

`[  371.544458] rtw_core: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[  371.544633] rtw_core: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel`

Comment: I reenabled the secure boot, now I get other error message: `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert rtw_8723de: Operation not permitted`

Comment: Please reboot and show us: `lsmod | grep rtw` and also: `sudo dmesg | grep 8723`

Comment: `lsmod | grep rtw` gives empty result. dmesg output:
`[    4.963605] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=000d lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=8723
[    4.964593] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723d_fw.bin
[    4.966893] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723d_config.bin
`

Comment: The driver did not load. Please again disable Secure Boot and try again: `lsmod | grep rtw` and also: `sudo dmesg | grep 8723` Please keep Secure Boot off if you need this wireless.

Comment: Above mentioned logs are made when secure boot was disabled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132715/discussion-between-chili555-and-daniel-kis).

Comment: This can't work, it's for `RTL8723DE`, not author's `RTL8723DU`

Answer (score 1):

You need a different driver, in terminal check `mokutil --sb-state` as Secure Boot needs to be disabled for the driver to load, then in terminal

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723du.git
sudo dkms add rtl8723du
sudo dkms install rtl8723du/0.1
```

Reboot

Ok there is an issue with the dkms.conf that causes problems, so do `sudo dkms remove rtl8723du/0.1 --all` and `sudo rm -r /usr/src/rtl8723du-0.1` Then go into the rtl8723du directory in your home directory and double click on dkms.conf and paste this in

```
PACKAGE_NAME="rtl8723du"
PACKAGE_VERSION=0.1
MAKE="'make' all KVER=${kernelver}"
CLEAN="make -C $kernel_source_dir clean"
BUILT_MODULE_NAME[0]="8723du"
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="/updates"
REMAKE_INITRD=no
AUTOINSTALL=yes
```

Save and exit, then do in terminal

```
sudo dkms add rtl8723du
sudo dkms install rtl8723du/0.1
```

Reboot if no errors

Comment: I get a following error message: 

make -j2 KERNELRELEASE=5.11.0-43-generic -C /lib/modules/5.11.0-43-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723du/0.1/build...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8723du: 0.1 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.11.0-43-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723du/0.1/build/make.log for more information.

Comment: ok, try `cd rtl8723du && make && sudo make install` then reboot

Comment: https://termbin.com/838a

Comment: Compiled without error messages, but It slow down the system after reboot. In journalctl there are lot of timeout entry: failed to activate service org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1: time out (service_start_timeout=25000ms). Therefore firefox not starts.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and run the wireless script, then do `cat wireless-info.txt | nc termbin.com 9999` and post URL

Comment: I have to reinstall the ubuntu, because the system slows down, network, and network related commands are frozen. After installation I run the above mentioned command, result can be found here: https://termbin.com/i9lv

Comment: I need the results after the driver is installed to see if some part of the driver is causing it

Comment: ```cd rtl8723du && make && sudo make install``` this works in case thanks You So Much,,, DKMS was giving same error to me

Answer (score 0):

[kablosuz ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekelebek333/+archive/ubuntu/kablosuz) has the necessary drivers:

```
mokutil --sb-state # check the output for "SecureBoot disabled", disable Secure Boot if not present 

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelebek333/kablosuz
sudo apt update
sudo apt install rtl8723du-dkms
# reboot the computer here
sudo modprobe 8723du
```