# Ubuntu can't find Wifi Driver on Maestro Laptop

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, support

I was using [this laptop](https://www.microcenter.com/product/646649/evolve-iii-maestro-e-book-116-laptop-computer-dark-grey) for art until I recently decided to switch to Linux for a better experience. I installed Ubuntu MATE and, from the first appearance, everything seemed fine.  However it took me a little bit to realize that setup did not ask for Wifi settings, nor did Wifi work after installation. There do not appear to be any wifi settings and, after using `sudo lshw -C net`, I was given this result:

```
*-usb:0 DISABLED,
description: interface,
product: EC25-AF,
vendor: Quectel,
physical id: 3,
bus info: usb@1:3,
logicalname:wwan0,
version: 3.18,
```

No WLAN device was detected. Even using `sudo lspci` didn't yield any results. Not even `sudo lsmod`. Is there any other way to find my wifi card?

Edit: Here is the full output of `sudo lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Host Bridge (rev 0b),
00:00.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 5a8c (rev 0b),
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 500 (rev 0b),
00:0e.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Audio Cluster (rev 0b),
00:0f.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 0b),
00:12.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SATA AHCI Controller (rev 0b),
00:13.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series PCI Express Port A #1 (rev FB),
00:13.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series PCI Express Port A #4 (rev FB),
00:14.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series PCI Express Port B #1 (rev FB),
00:14.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series PCI Express Port B #2 (rev FB),
00:15.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series USB xHCI (rev 0b),
00:16.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #1 (rev 0b),
00:16.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #2 (rev 0b),
00:16.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #3 (rev 0b),
00:16.3 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #4 (rev 0b),
00:17.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #5 (rev 0b),
00:17.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #6 (rev 0b),
00:17.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #7 (rev 0b),
00:17.3 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #8 (rev 0b),
00:18.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller #1 (rev 0b),
00:18.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller #2 (rev 0b),
00:18.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller #3 (rev 0b),
00:18.3 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller #4 (rev 0b),
00:19.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SPI Controller #1 (rev 0b),
00:19.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SPI Controller #2 (rev 0b),
00:19.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SPI Controller #3 (rev 0b),
00:1c.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series eMMC Controller (rev 0b),
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Low Pin Count Interface (rev 0b),
00:1f.1 SMBus: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SMBus Controller (rev 0b)
```

`sudo lsusb` outputs:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub,
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 058f:3822 Alcor Micro Corp. USB 2.0 Camera ,
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:d723 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11n WLAN Adapter,
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller,
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2c7c:0125 Quectel Wireless Solutions Co., Ltd. EC25 LTE modem,
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver,
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Yesterday the WLAN Adapter did not show with `sudo lsusb`, I guess it shows now. Is there anyone who knows the proper driver for the adapter?

(Also thanks for those who edited the question, I am new to this site)

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the full Terminal output of `sudo lspci` and `sudo lsusb`? This may help someone identify which wireless device is being used in your system 

Comment: I added the output to `sudo lspci` and `sudo lsusb`

Comment: Did you check `rfkill`?

Comment: rfkill only shows bluetooth

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1384282/1222991) from December should work for you 

Comment: I tried using it, it installs, and modprobe activates it, it does show any Wifi connections or changes.

Comment: @Jeff No, Ubuntu is supposed to load the drivers automatically, if they are free and open source. The user is not supposed to download them from Debian.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Alright. That is good to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for helping. I was able to get it working using lwfinger's rtl8723du drivers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That's a pretty sketchy laptop for Linux. Personally I prefer to use Dell laptops. Yes you pay a little more but I buy them two years after they were top-of-the-line and buy the gaming models.

The first specification that raises an eyebrow with your laptop is this:

- Microsoft Windows 10 Pro Education

Really there should be some sort of vetting process for a retailer to sell MS special licenses like this.

Obviously such a retailer on thin margins is not going to test the laptop for Linux in general and, Ubuntu specifically.