# Not able to connect wireless wifi in Ubuntu 23.04 on a old 5-6 year old pc

Tags: xubuntu

i just downloaded the ubuntu 23.04 version in my pc and now am not able to connect to wifi , i tried various online commands available and tried to use Hidden networks but its not working so i am here asking some solution to this.

Comment: Could you provide system specs? We can't give an appropriate and accurate answer without them. Just remember that in the future, I guess

Comment: Also, this may help. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1397572/ubuntu-cant-find-wifi-driver-on-maestro-laptop/1398458#1398458

Comment: Edit your question and provide complete details. *"I tried various commands"* does not convey any information that could be useful in helping you solve your issue. You should tell us exactly what you did as well as the detailed results of your attempts. Use the exact terms, commands, outputs, etc.  Don't paraphrase in your own words or summarize to the point that all of the useful information is gone. With clear and complete details we may be able to use that information to determine a cause and/or solution to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect via a wired connection, get a few tools. wifi-radar is one. inxi is another one:

First you try wifi-radar:

```
sudo apt-install wifi-radar
wifi-radar
```

If this shows the available wifi networks, you are fine. Otherwise:

```
sudo apt install inxi
inxi -nx
```

Other people will probably give you other advice, there are many useful tools around. No harm in trying them all (as long as they are only diagnosing tools). Then you post the output here, so people will have an idea about what precisely is wrong with your system.

5 or 6 years old is not that old :)