# Wireless card driver is driving me crazy!

Tags: drivers, xubuntu, realtek-wireless

It's been a while since I got my laptop, after searching lots of solutions for the drivers of my Wireless card, none of them seem to be permanent and working properly. Sometimes it just makes my Network manager go crazy or doing something like completely ignoring installed drivers after a few days.

My kernel version: 4.15.0-50-generic

My hardware: Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d723
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8319

And I followed this thread [Cannot see my wifi [10ec:d723] when trying Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961299/cannot-see-my-wifi-10ecd723-when-trying-ubuntu)
that gave me a temporary solution.

I ended up deleting linux-headers and following the dkms instructions, but after this command:

`sudo dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414`

I get this errors:

```
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8723de: 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414 not found

Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-50-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/make.log for more information.
```

I'm hopeless, been trying to solve this for a long time without really caring, but now I need it and I have no idea what to do!

Thanks in advance for everyone kind enough to help me.

Here is the error:

```
DKMS make.log for rtl8723de-5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414 for kernel 4.15.0-51-generic (x86_64)
mié jun  5 12:49:34 -03 2019
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-51-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-51-generic'
Makefile:976: "Cannot use CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel"
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_cmd.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_security.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_debug.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_io.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_ioctl_query.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_ioctl_set.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_ieee80211.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_mlme.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_mlme_ext.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_mi.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_wlan_util.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_vht.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_pwrctrl.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_rf.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_recv.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_sta_mgt.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_ap.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_xmit.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_p2p.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_tdls.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_br_ext.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_iol.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_sreset.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_btcoex.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_beamforming.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_odm.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/efuse/rtw_efuse.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/os_dep/osdep_service.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:1210:22: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 .ndo_select_queue = rtw_select_queue,
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:1210:22: note: (near initialization for ‘rtw_netdev_ops.ndo_select_queue’)
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/os_dep/linux/pci_intf.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/os_dep/linux/pci_ops_linux.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/os_dep/linux/ioctl_linux.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/os_dep/linux/xmit_linux.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/os_dep/linux/mlme_linux.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/os_dep/linux/recv_linux.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/os_dep/linux/rtw_cfgvendor.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/os_dep/linux/wifi_regd.o
 CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.o
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.c: In function ‘rtw_android_priv_cmd’:
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.c:635:49: error: macro "access_ok" requires 3 arguments, but only 2 given
 if (!access_ok(priv_cmd.buf, priv_cmd.total_len)) {
                                                ^
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.c:635:7: error: ‘access_ok’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 if (!access_ok(priv_cmd.buf, priv_cmd.total_len)) {
      ^~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.c:635:7: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
scripts/Makefile.build:330: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.o] Error 1
Makefile:1552: recipe for target '_module_/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-51-generic'
Makefile:1885: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Comment: More information is in the file `/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/make.log`, just like the error message says.

Comment: DKMS probably needs the Linux headers too.

Comment: Never delete your Linux headers. You won't be able to compile anything.